# How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?

Tags: python

How do I find the location of my `site-packages` directory?

Comment: If you just want the exact location of one package then you can use `pip show <package name>`

Answer (score 1097, accepted):

There are two types of site-packages directories, *global* and *per user*.

1. **Global** site-packages ("[dist-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages)") directories are listed in `sys.path` when you run:

   ```
    python -m site
   ```

   For a more concise list run `getsitepackages` from the [site module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.getsitepackages) in Python code:

   ```
    python -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages())'
   ```

   *Caution:* In virtual environments [getsitepackages is not available](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/228) with [older versions of `virtualenv`](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/2379/files), `sys.path` from above will list the virtualenv's site-packages directory correctly, though. In Python 3, you may use the [sysconfig module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#using-sysconfig-as-a-script) instead:

   ```
    python3 -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths()["purelib"])'
   ```
2. The **per user** site-packages directory ([PEP 370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)) is where Python installs your local packages:

   ```
    python -m site --user-site
   ```

   If this points to a non-existing directory check the exit status of Python and see `python -m site --help` for explanations.

   *Hint:* Running `pip list --user` or `pip freeze --user` gives you a list of all installed *per user* site-packages.

---

### Practical Tips

- `<package>.__path__` lets you identify the location(s) of a specific package: ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for))

  ```
    $ python -c "import setuptools as _; print(_.__path__)"
    ['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools']
  ```
- `<module>.__file__` lets you identify the location of a specific module: ([difference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111871/module-vs-package))

  ```
    $ python3 -c "import os as _; print(_.__file__)"
    /usr/lib/python3.6/os.py
  ```
- Run `pip show <package>` to show Debian-style package information:

  ```
    $ pip show pytest
    Name: pytest
    Version: 3.8.2
    Summary: pytest: simple powerful testing with Python
    Home-page: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/
    Author: Holger Krekel, Bruno Oliveira, Ronny Pfannschmidt, Floris Bruynooghe, Brianna Laugher, Florian Bruhin and others
    Author-email: None
    License: MIT license
    Location: /home/peter/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
    Requires: more-itertools, atomicwrites, setuptools, attrs, pathlib2, six, py, pluggy
  ```

Comment: there is a site package directory in a virtualenv. You can get  the
  directory for site-specific modules inside/outside virtualenv using [`python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122340/4279) (it works on both Python 2 and 3 too).

Comment: Nice. And to get the first one: `python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])"`

Comment: This should be in any basic tutorial on using python. I've been pythoning for years and didn't know about the site module. Would've saved so many headaches...

Comment: I have suggested a change to Python's official tutorial. Please see [PR #16974](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/16974) for details, and thanks for the suggestion @salotz!

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/52638888/1365918 is easily the best answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks Peterino, command `python3 -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths()["purelib"])'` saved me some hours for debuging package when compile tensorflow with bazel.

Comment: `sysconfig.get_path("purelib")`

Comment: virtualenvs was rewritten after v20.0.0b1, now `site.getsitepackages` is available. see https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2378

Comment: I wasn't using virutalenv, and upon investigation the root cause I found is : my default python version is 3.8, but Gunicorn decided to default to use 3.9

Comment: One can also use `python -c "import site; print(site.USER_SITE)"` to get the same output as `python -m site --user-site`.

Answer (score 700):

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

(or just first item with `site.getsitepackages()[0]`)

Comment: This is good but, unfortunately, this function is available only from python2.7.

So, nice solution if you are using python2.7 or above, but not working for python 2.6 and below

Comment: @TonySeek: I just tried with pypy (2.0.2) and it works just fine.

Comment: python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getsitepackages' when using with virtualenv (python 2.7.8), the distutils solution below works though.

Comment: @radtek: for venv's, I detect venv via `hasattr(sys,'real_prefix')` and then determine site packages heuristically from `[p for p in sys.path if p.endswith('site-packages')][-1]` (plus check if there is one found before doing the `[-1]`.

Comment: how can I setup local site folder to my home location?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ create a separate question for that, you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @radtek It is a known bug that the site module does not work for virtualenv https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/355

Comment: @eudoxos is right. You can get all the paths if you use `sys.path`.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ You can just use `pip install --user PACKAGE_NAME`

Answer (score 384):

A solution that:

- outside of virtualenv - provides the path of **global** site-packages,
- insidue a virtualenv - provides the **virtualenv's** site-packages

...is this one-liner:

```py
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
```

Formatted for readability (rather than use as a one-liner), that looks like the following:

```py
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib())
```

*Source:* an very old version of ["How to Install Django" documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20100723105725/http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/install#removing-old-versions-of-django) (though this is useful to more than just Django installation)

Comment: Does virtualenv provide a way to find its site-packages?

Comment: You can use virtualenvwrapper, which has the command `cdsitepackages`, to directly change into the environment's site-packages directory.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: works for me on Python 2.7 in a virtualenv on Linux

Comment: First comment does not apply anymore: this showed the correct location both outside and inside a virtualenv.

Comment: @njwilson Thanks for the solution. Really helped. in windows system, it normally stays in Python Path\Lib\site-packages

Comment: Did not work for me on Windows 10 using Linux bash, it returns `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` instead of `/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`.

Comment: @Delgan, I imagine that `/usr/lib/python3` is a symlink to `/usr/lib/python3.5`.On my Cygwin,I get the following: `which python3` gives `/usr/bin/python3`, but I find out _that_ is a symlink in several ways.`readlink -f /usr/bin/python3` => `/usr/bin/python3.6m.exe`. `stat /usr/bin/python3` gives output beginning with `File: /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6m.exe` and has `symbolic link` in the output. `ls -lah /usr/bin/python3` has as its last column `/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6m.exe`.Those are executables and not library directories. My lib dirs don't have symlinks, but Cygwin != "Linux bash".

Comment: The answer has become outdated - distutils is now [deprecated](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/).

Answer (score 109):

*For Ubuntu*,

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"
```

...is not correct.

It will point you to `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages`

This folder only contains packages your operating system has automatically installed for programs to run.

*On ubuntu*, the site-packages folder that contains packages installed via setup_tools\easy_install\pip will be in `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages`

The second folder is probably the more useful one if the use case is related to installation or reading source code.

If you do not use Ubuntu, you are probably safe copy-pasting the first code box into the terminal.

Comment: If the asker is after a particular package's location, `module.__file__` is the better way. If they're trying to install things… just use the tools.

Comment: `'/usr/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages' in site.getsitepackages()` on Ubuntu (though it goes *after* `/usr/local/...` in the list). You only get something into `/usr/local` via `sudo pip` and you shouldn't use `sudo pip` on Ubuntu unless you decided to make your own distribution: if you use `sudo pip`, it is your responsibility to make sure that all dependencies of the current and *future* python modules installed via `sudo apt` or `sudo pip` are compatible. Consider [what problem `virtualenv` was created to solve](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/#introduction)

Comment: `python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_unixsocket'`

Answer (score 86):

This is what worked for me:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

Comment: For me this points to a folder that doesn't even exist (`~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`).

Comment: same, in OS X Mavericks , my home .local isn't what I wanted it to find plus yeah its not really there anyways.

Comment: Its in my main /Library folder I had to manually navigate to it, for some reason the direct full path wasn't working

Comment: how do i use the packages installed here? if i do `virtualenv` it complains that the package does not exist. how do i invoke the packages installed at a custom location?

Comment: for me this answer works neither on osx inside or outside virtualenv nor on ubuntu without virtualenv.

Comment: This is useful in specific circumstances. For example, if you're using setuptools, you might invoke develop with something like `python setup.py develop --script-dir ~/bin --install-dir /home/thomp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: This tells you where Python will look for user specific packages. Comments like "doesn't even exist" and "isn't what I wanted it to find" don't make sense in this context.

Comment: import site; site.getusersitepackages()

Answer (score 71):

A modern stdlib way is using [`sysconfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html) module, available in version 2.7 and 3.2+. **Unlike the current accepted answer, this method still works regardless of whether or not you have a virtual environment active.**

*Note*: `sysconfig` ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/sysconfig)) is not to be confused with the `distutils.sysconfig` submodule ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.6/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py)) mentioned in several other answers here. The latter is an entirely different module and it's lacking the `get_paths` function discussed below. Additionally, `distutils` was [deprecated in Python 3.10](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/) and [removed in Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#distutils).

Python currently uses *eight* paths ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#installation-paths)):

> - *stdlib*: directory containing the standard Python library files that are not platform-specific.
> - *platstdlib*: directory containing the standard Python library files that are platform-specific.
> - *platlib*: directory for site-specific, platform-specific files.
> - *purelib*: directory for site-specific, non-platform-specific files.
> - *include*: directory for non-platform-specific header files.
> - *platinclude*: directory for platform-specific header files.
> - *scripts*: directory for script files.
> - *data*: directory for data files.

In most cases, users finding this question would be interested in the 'purelib' path (in [some  cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122387/674039), you might be interested in 'platlib' too). The purelib path is where ordinary Python packages will be installed by tools like [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/).

At system level, you'll see something like this:

```
# Linux
$ python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('purelib'))"
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

# macOS (brew installed python3.8)
$ python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('purelib'))"
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages

# Windows
C:\> py -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('purelib'))"
C:\Users\wim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages
```

With a venv, you'll get something like this

```
# Linux
/tmp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages

# macOS
/private/tmp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages

# Windows
C:\Users\wim\AppData\Local\Temp\.venv\Lib\site-packages
```

The function [`sysconfig.get_paths()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#sysconfig.get_paths) returns a dict of all of the relevant installation paths, example on Linux:

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_paths()
{'stdlib': '/usr/local/lib/python3.8',
 'platstdlib': '/usr/local/lib/python3.8',
 'purelib': '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 'platlib': '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 'include': '/usr/local/include/python3.8',
 'platinclude': '/usr/local/include/python3.8',
 'scripts': '/usr/local/bin',
 'data': '/usr/local'}
```

A shell script is also available to display these details, which you can invoke by executing `sysconfig` as a module:

```
python -m sysconfig
```

##### *Addendum*: What about Debian / Ubuntu?

As some commenters point out, the sysconfig results for Debian systems (and Ubuntu, as a derivative) are not accurate. When a user pip installs a package it will go into *dist-packages* not *site-packages*, as per [Debian policies on Python packaging](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/index.html#module-path).

The root cause of the discrepancy is because Debian [patch the distutils install layout](https://salsa.debian.org/cpython-team/python3/-/blob/master/debian/patches/distutils-install-layout.diff), to correctly reflect their changes to the site, but they fail to patch the sysconfig module.

For example, on *Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)*:

```
root@cb5e85f17c7f:/# python3 -m sysconfig | grep packages
    platlib = "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
    purelib = "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages"

root@cb5e85f17c7f:/# python3 -m site | grep packages
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
```

It looks like the patched Python installation that Debian/Ubuntu are distributing is a bit [hacked up](https://gist.github.com/tiran/2dec9e03c6f901814f6d1e8dad09528e), and they will need to figure out a new plan for 3.12+ when distutils is completely unavailable. Probably, they will have to [start patching sysconfig as well](https://salsa.debian.org/cpython-team/python3/-/blob/master/debian/patches/sysconfig-debian-schemes.diff), since this is what pip will be using for install locations.

Comment: This is a great answer, I am happy the new sysconfig module makes this easier. Is there a way to get the local prefix `platlib`, as e.g. `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`? Traditionally, locally-installed things should go in `/usr/local`.

Comment: Easily the best answer to this question! Thank you. The only thing that I found missing was the ordering in which these locations are checked when an import statement is encountered. Also, are any of these locations pre-searched/cached when python is loaded? Knowing that would also be useful IMO.

Comment: In a venv created with `--system-site-packages` this doesn't list all searched directories - specifically the system site directories that are still searched are not listed here...

Comment: Agree with other comments. This is a fantastic answer to the question and works in all contexts I've tried it in.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer has a fatal flaw: the `sysconfig` module does not produce correct paths on Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives, whereas the `distutils.sysconfig` module does.

Comment: I confirm this provide incorrect paths for me on ubuntu

Comment: @Alleo Added an addendum to the answer after investigating what's going on with this distro. What a can of worms. Here's a long [list of stuff Debian messed up in Python](https://gist.github.com/tiran/2dec9e03c6f901814f6d1e8dad09528e).

Comment: @wim that's where I ended up after investigations. This could be just it - screwed up python distro, however when I tried deadsnakes (independent PPA for ubuntu), sysconfig and site provided a different set of paths, which - surprise - again were not in sys.path. I am not sure I have a solution, but I agree about "a can of worms" experience

Comment: @Alleo See [bug #1940705: _distutils and sysconfig returns unexpected paths_](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.10/+bug/1940705)

Answer (score 37):

Let's say you have installed the package 'django'. import it and type in dir(django). It will show you, all the functions and attributes with that module. Type in the python interpreter -

```
>>> import django
>>> dir(django)
['VERSION', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'get_version']
>>> print django.__path__
['/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django']
```

You can do the same thing if you have installed mercurial.

This is for Snow Leopard. But I think it should work in general as well.

Comment: >>> import pg
>>> print pg.__path__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

Comment: it works, i need to find the sklearn package to add to the PYDEV path, thanks.

Comment: use `django.__file__` for this rather than `__path__`.  and, no, it's not a guarantee that this has anything to do with site-packages, but with things like django, that you've most likely *pip installed*, it will do when you're in a hurry and it can be used for other purposes as well (reading a default config file from the file system for example).

Comment: Based on this and other answers you can do this in one line from the command line to get the path to your `foo.bar` package: `python -c "import foo.bar as _; print(_.__path__[0])"`

Answer (score 29):

As others have noted, `distutils.sysconfig` has the relevant settings:

```
import distutils.sysconfig
print distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()
```

...though the default `site.py` does something a bit more crude, paraphrased below:

```
import sys, os
print os.sep.join([sys.prefix, 'lib', 'python' + sys.version[:3], 'site-packages'])
```

(it also adds `${sys.prefix}/lib/site-python` and adds both paths for `sys.exec_prefix` as well, should that constant be different).

That said, what's the context? You shouldn't be messing with your `site-packages` directly; setuptools/distutils will work for installation, and your program may be running in a virtualenv where your pythonpath is completely user-local, so it shouldn't assume use of the system site-packages directly either.

Comment: works  reliable with `python2` on osx and ubuntu with and without virtualenv but not with `python3` at all.

Comment: 2008 was a while back -- this answer was three months before Python 3.0's release.

Comment: sure, but today my comment might help. correct me if am wrong. furthermore, i did not downvote this answer or any other in regards to `python3`.

Answer (score 27):

pip show will give all the details about a package:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/  [pip show][1]

To get the location:

```
pip show <package_name>| grep Location
```

In Linux, you can go to site-packages folder by:

```
cd $(python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])")
```

Comment: Adding OS X's 'cut' command to the end of that will give you the string too: ```pip3 show foo | grep Location | cut -d ' ' -f 2```

Comment: For Windows, when it _must_ be used, `findstr` instead of `grep` works. So, `python -m pip show numpy | findstr "Location"` gives `Location: c:\users\bballdave025\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages`. Modules you have installed with `pip` are in `site packages`. You can be pretty sure `site-packages` is the location of `pip` itself - as called with `python -m pip ...`. So, `python -m pip show pip | findstr "Location"` shows the same path to `site-packages` we got from `numpy`. Besides `pip`, you can almost always try `virtualenv` (`venv`) & `setuptools`, for *NIX *or* Win

Answer (score 25):

The native system packages installed with python installation in Debian based systems can be found at :

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

In OSX - `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

by using this small code :

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print get_python_lib()
```

However, the list of packages installed via `pip` can be found at :

> /usr/local/bin/

Or one can simply write the following command to list all paths where python packages are.

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

*Note: the location might vary based on your OS, like in OSX*

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, dist-packages is specific to Debian and derivates.

Comment: @SamuelSantana you are correct. dist-packages are specific to debian based systems. In this case I invoked `site.getsitepackages()` from the system installation hence the dist-packages, other installations will show site-packages.

Answer (score 15):

All the answers (or: the same answer repeated over and over) are inadequate. What you want to do is this:

```
from setuptools.command.easy_install import easy_install
class easy_install_default(easy_install):
  """ class easy_install had problems with the fist parameter not being
      an instance of Distribution, even though it was. This is due to
      some import-related mess.
      """

  def __init__(self):
    from distutils.dist import Distribution
    dist = Distribution()
    self.distribution = dist
    self.initialize_options()
    self._dry_run = None
    self.verbose = dist.verbose
    self.force = None
    self.help = 0
    self.finalized = 0

e = easy_install_default()
import distutils.errors
try:
  e.finalize_options()
except distutils.errors.DistutilsError:
  pass

print e.install_dir
```

The final line shows you the installation dir. Works on Ubuntu, whereas the above ones don't. Don't ask me about windows or other dists, but since it's the exact same dir that easy_install uses by default, it's probably correct everywhere where easy_install works (so, everywhere, even macs). Have fun. Note: original code has many swearwords in it.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty useful, on py3 with brackets for print it gets me 
  /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages 
I'm trying to work out how to get 
  /usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
so will have to play further.

Comment: requires external library `easy_install` and does not fail gracefully if unavailable which is inadequate :)

Comment: indeed, this is not perfect, but it worked for me and took a lot of time to figure out, so I put it here in hopes someone else can build upon the time I've spent on it already.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me.
It will get you both dist-packages and site-packages folders.
If the folder is not on Python's path, it won't be
doing you much good anyway.

```
import sys; 
print [f for f in sys.path if f.endswith('packages')]
```

Output (Ubuntu installation):

```
['/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Comment: accepted answer is the recommended way, so you should tell why yours is better, since it's a bit of a hack

Comment: What's wrong with a hack? ;)  It's simpler and easy to understand and remember if you're working interactively.

Answer (score 14):

An additional note to the `get_python_lib` function mentioned already: on some platforms different directories are used for platform specific modules (eg: modules that require compilation).  If you pass `plat_specific=True` to the function you get the site packages for platform specific packages.

Answer (score 14):

A side-note: The proposed solution (`distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()`) does not work when there is more than one site-packages directory (as [recommended by this article](http://pythonsimple.noucleus.net/python-install/python-site-packages-what-they-are-and-where-to-put-them)). It will only return the main site-packages directory.

Alas, I have no better solution either. Python doesn't seem to keep track of site-packages directories, just the packages within them.

Comment: I guess that's the reason why `get_python_lib()` when being run from within virtualenv shows *site-packages* of Python used to create virtualenv and not the virtualenv's *site-packages*.

Comment: @Piotr That was probably a bug in distutils.sysconfig. I've just tested it an I get the inner site-packages, as expected.

Comment: Also tested with Python 2.7 installed in a virtualenv on Linux, and the distutils.sysconfig method works fine to get the inner Python's site-packages.

Answer (score 14):

This should work on all distributions in and out of virtual environment due to it's "low-tech" nature. The os module always resides in the parent directory of 'site-packages'

```
import os; print(os.path.dirname(os.__file__) + '/site-packages')
```

To change dir to the site-packages dir I use the following alias (on *nix systems):

```
alias cdsp='cd $(python -c "import os; print(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))"); cd site-packages'
```

Comment: I like your low tech approach.   Here is a platform independant version:
import os; print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.__file__), 'site-packages'))

Comment: my original code is platform-independent too. Windows accepts both forward slashes ('/') and back slashes (`\`) just fine as path separators. It is just more common on Windows to use the back slashes.

Answer (score 10):

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print get_python_lib()
```

Answer (score 8):

You should try this command to determine pip's install location

Python 2

```
pip show six | grep "Location:" | cut -d " " -f2
```

Python **3**

```
pip3 show six | grep "Location:" | cut -d " " -f2
```

Answer (score 5):

Answer to old question. But use ipython for this.

```
pip install ipython
ipython 
import imaplib
imaplib?
```

This will give the following output about imaplib package -

```
Type:        module
String form: <module 'imaplib' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py'>
File:        /usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py
Docstring:  
IMAP4 client.

Based on RFC 2060.

Public class:           IMAP4
Public variable:        Debug
Public functions:       Internaldate2tuple
                        Int2AP
                        ParseFlags
                        Time2Internaldate
```

Comment: This isn't the site-packages directory, but the directory that the package is installed into. This is also only helpful if you're using iPython and not for being able to programmatically get an install directory.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), you can find your virtual environment path with `poetry debug`:

```sh
$ poetry debug

Poetry
Version: 1.1.4
Python:  3.8.2

Virtualenv
Python:         3.8.2
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/cglacet/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/my-virtualenv
Valid:          True

System
Platform: darwin
OS:       posix
Python:   /Users/cglacet/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2
```

Using this information you can list site packages:

```sh
ls /Users/cglacet/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
```

Answer (score 3):

## I made a really simple function that gets the job done

```py
import site


def get_site_packages_dir():
        return [p for p  in site.getsitepackages()
                if p.endswith(("site-packages", "dist-packages"))][0]

get_site_packages_dir()
# '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages'
```

## If you want to retrieve the results using the terminal:

```sh
python3 -c "import site;print([p for p in site.getsitepackages() if p.endswith(('site-packages', 'dist-packages')) ][0])"

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Comment: This doesn't work on eg. Ubuntu, where the site-packages directory is named `dist-packages`... Not at all reliable.

Comment: @rdb just edited the answer (did not know that it was `dist-packages` on Ubunut, now it includes  `dist-packages`

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something slightly different for a project I was working on: find the *relative* site-packages directory relative to the base install prefix.  If the site-packages folder was in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, I wanted the `/lib/python2.7/site-packages` part.  I have, in fact, encountered systems where `site-packages` was in `/usr/lib64`, and the accepted answer did NOT work on those systems.

Similar to cheater's answer, my solution peeks deep into the guts of Distutils, to find the path that actually gets passed around inside `setup.py`.  It was such a pain to figure out that I don't want anyone to ever have to figure this out again.

```
import sys
import os
from distutils.command.install import INSTALL_SCHEMES

if os.name == 'nt':
    scheme_key = 'nt'
else:
    scheme_key = 'unix_prefix'

print(INSTALL_SCHEMES[scheme_key]['purelib'].replace('$py_version_short', (str.split(sys.version))[0][0:3]).replace('$base', ''))
```

That should print something like `/Lib/site-packages` or `/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Answer (score 2):

Something that has not been mentioned which I believe is useful, if you have two versions of Python installed e.g. both 3.8 and 3.5 there might be two folders called site-packages on your machine. In that case you can specify the python version by using the following:

```
py -3.5 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[1])
```