# django 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'field'

Tags: django, apache, file-upload, nginx, mod-wsgi

I'm having a problem uploading files on my production server.  I'm using the django-stdimage on a model as follows:

```
class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = StdImageField(upload_to='images/league_logos', blank=True, size=(220, 120))
```

Using the admin app, I can upload templates on my local machine (using the dev server) just fine.  On production, I have nginx for static file retrieval and apache with mod_wsgi for the rest.  When trying to upload on production, I get the

'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'field'

error.  I'm tailing the error log in apache and nothing seems to happen when I try to upload.  The error is happening at

site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19

which is just a template tag accessing the field.field:

```
{{ field.field }}
```

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to be due to PIL not getting installed when I pip installed my requirements.  That was a very frustrating issue since the error message didn't really clue me into that.

Luckily I came across this thread:

[Why can't I upload jpg files to my Django app via admin/?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402002/why-cant-i-upload-jpg-files-to-my-django-app-via-admin)

which clued me in.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to pass it a filesystem storage object - then it knows how to convert the InMemoryUploadedFile object that it gets from your browser to an ImageFieldFile, so it can save the image.

```
# Near top of your file:
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# Then in your model:
    logo = StdImageField(storage = fs, upload_to='images/league_logos', blank=True, size=(220, 120))
```

That should save uploaded files to MEDIA_ROOT/images/league_logos.