# How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, pythonpath

I have a directory which hosts all of my Django apps (`C:\My_Projects`). I want to add this directory to my `PYTHONPATH` so I can call the apps directly.

I tried adding `C:\My_Projects\;` to my Windows `Path` variable from the Windows GUI (`My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables`). But it still doesn't read the coltrane module and generates this error:

> Error: No module named coltrane

Comment: for "no module named" error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417941/python-import-error-no-module-named-does-exist/40883739#40883739

Comment: I used [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.addsitedir1).

Comment: if you want to run python in command prompt it is answered well here I hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/54618199/8253662

Comment: "I want to add this directory to my PYTHONPATH so I can call the apps directly. I tried adding C:\My_Projects\; to my Windows Path variable" - well, yes, of course that doesn't work: the PATH variable is not the same as the PYTHONPATH variable.

Answer (score 484, accepted):

You know what has worked for me really well on windows.

`My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >`

Just add the path as C:\Python27 (or wherever you installed python)

OR

Then under system variables I create a new Variable called `PythonPath`. In this variable I have `C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\other-folders-on-the-path`

[image]

This is the best way that has worked for me which I hadn't found in any of the docs offered.

**EDIT:** For those who are not able to get it,
Please add

> C:\Python27;

along with it. Else it will *never work*.

Comment: You probably want to add `C:\Python27` in your path.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost that link is broken for me now. Is this the application you recommend: [http://patheditor2.codeplex.com/](patheditor2 at codeplex)

Comment: @SteveKoch I'm not sure — you would have to ask project's maintener. I no longer use Path Editor as I switched to much better [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com)

Comment: It's also important to add C:\Python27\Scripts to the path so that installed scripts can be run from the shell.

Comment: Why would you put `C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk` in `PYTHONPATH`? Those are already configured. Directories for scripts go in the system `PATH`. Directories for libraries (that aren't installed to `site-packages` or the per-user `site-packages`) go in `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: He probably did that because none of of it particularly clear or well organized in any of the documentation, or in any of the tutorials that I've found. It's all a bit too vague, which is strange considering how, back when I was a young chap and python was just getting started, python modeled itself as the ideal language for programming newbies..

Comment: I had to include %PYTHONPATH% in my PATH as well.

Comment: Remember restart your computer

Comment: No need to restart computer, just need to open up a new command prompt and it should work.

Comment: Thanks darren.. I know this is an old thread but it helped me in setting up node js.. This worked.. I had Python 3.6 and by default it installs in Program Files. I tried installing it to Python36 after seeing your solution. It did not work. Then I uninstalled Python 3.6 and installed Python 2.7 to Python27 folder and it worked..I had to include %PYTHONPATH% in my PATH as well... Have you found out why this is so?

Comment: If you want to open this from the command line, `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` works. I put it in a batch file `env.bat`.

Comment: for python3.8, Python38-32\Lib doesn't contain lib-tk. This means, isn't required to add lib-tk path in PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 138):

Windows 7 Professional
I Modified @mongoose_za's answer to make it easier to change the python version:

1. [Right Click]Computer > Properties >Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
2. Click [New] under "System Variable"
3. Variable Name: PY_HOME, Variable Value:C:\path\to\python\version
   [image]
4. Click [OK]
5. Locate the "Path" System variable and click [Edit]
6. Add the following to the existing variable:

   %PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk;
   [image]
7. Click [OK] to close all of the windows.

As a final sanity check open a command prompt and enter python. You should see

```
>python [whatever version you are using]
```

If you need to switch between versions, you only need to modify the PY_HOME variable to point to the proper directory. This is bit easier to manage if you need multiple python versions installed.

Comment: Tried this and it worked... i would recommend anyone going through the same problem to try this.

Comment: Tried this, it didn't do anything at all.

Comment: I tried the accepted answer above and that didn't work so I would recommend this one.

Comment: By "Variable Value:C:\path\to\python\version" do you mean the address of the directory that included python.exe?

Comment: @Reihan_amn I mean the wrapping directory that contains the lib, bin, libexec, etc.  Typically these directories are named Python[VERSION_NUMBER]/, but I have also seen python/[VERSION_NUMBER]. Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me.  I had to make one small adjustment which was to click New for each of these entries for Windows 10 when adding them to the PATH variable. `%PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk;`  I also needed to add `%PY_HOME%\Scripts` so I had access to pip and the modules I install with pip such as pylint

Answer (score 124):

From Windows command line:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
```

To set the PYTHONPATH permanently, add the line to your `autoexec.bat`. Alternatively, if you edit the system variable through the System Properties, it will also be changed permanently.

Comment: Worked but everytime I open dos I had to set the path.

Comment: I prefer to use `set path=%PATH%;%PYTHONPATH%;`

Comment: Dos and editing autoexec.bat..! Have we suddenly slipped back into the 90s?

Comment: Before this, do  **echo %PYTHONPATH%** if this gives you a path go on, otherwise, do e.g. **set PYTHONPATH=.;C:\My_python_lib** If you don't, windows will expand %PYTHONPATH% to empty string as expected, it will keep it as  %PYTHONPATH% in the PYTHONPATH and everything will break! Sounds crazy but thats how win7 cmd works...

Comment: To make it permanent, use `setx` instead of `set`.

Comment: Note that the syntax differs if using `setx`, per @AmitNaidu's suggestion - I think it would be `setx PYTHONPATH %PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib` or `set PYTHONPATH .;C:\My_python_lib`. And note that your path can't contain spaces (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69246810/4659442)

Answer (score 64):

These solutions work, but they work for your code ONLY on your machine. I would add a couple of lines to your code that look like this:

```
import sys
if "C:\\My_Python_Lib" not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("C:\\My_Python_Lib")
```

That should take care of your problems

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` like this is frowned upon and for good reasons. There are better ways of configuring `sys.path` — `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and `.pth` files.

Answer (score 58):

**Just append** your installation path (ex. `C:\Python27\`) to the **PATH** variable in **System variables**. Then close and open your **command line and type `python`**.

Comment: This is answering a completely different question than the one OP was asking.

Comment: The question isn't about the `PATH` that DOS uses to find commands, but the Python path, i.e. `sys.path` in Python. In most operating systems, Python just uses the system environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, but Windows seems to be 'special'.

Answer (score 43):

Adding *Python* and *PythonPath* to the Windows environment:

1. Open Explorer.
2. Right-click *'Computer'* in the Navigation Tree Panel on the left.
3. Select *'Properties'* at the bottom of the Context Menu.
4. Select *'Advanced system settings'*
5. Click *'Environment Variables...'* in the Advanced Tab
6. Under *'System Variables'*:

   1. Add

      - `PY_HOME`

        ```
        C:\Python27
        ```
      - `PYTHONPATH`

        ```
        %PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk;C:\another-library
        ```
   2. Append

      - `path`

        ```
        %PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Scripts\
        ```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Also, for those of you who do not have administrator rights, just follow the steps above under "User variables for [yourUsername]" and it will work just as well.

Comment: Python on Windows, appreciating node.js a little more right now

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way to do that successfully, is to run the python installer again (after the first installation) and then:

1. choose Modify.
2. check the optional features which you want and click Next.
3. here we go, in "Advanced Options" step you must see an option saying "Add Python to environment variables". Just check that option and click Install.
   [image: 3rd step]
   When the installation is completed, python environment variables are added and you can easily use python everywhere.

Comment: Setting this variable globally through the Environment Variables settings is not recommended, as it may be used by any version of Python instead of the one that you intend to use.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/python/faqs

Comment: Also, I tried this, does not work. Still not in my path.

Answer (score 19):

The easier way to set the path in python is : 
click start> My Computer >Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >
second windows >

[image]

select Path > Edit > and then add ";C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\"

link :http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/

Comment: changing system path changed nothing (deleting it too). But typing in admin cmd worked:    ftype Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

Answer (score 15):

You need to add to your **PYTHONPATH** variable instead of Windows **PATH** variable.

http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html

Answer (score 15):

You can also add a `.pth` file containing the desired directory in either your `c:\PythonX.X` folder, or your `\site-packages folder`, which tends to be my preferred method when I'm developing a Python package.

See [here](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/02/06/using-pth-files-for-python-development/) for more information.

Answer (score 13):

The PYTHONPATH environment variable is used by Python to specify a list of directories that modules can be imported from on Windows. When running, you can inspect the `sys.path` variable to see which directories will be searched when you import something.

To set this variable from the Command Prompt, use: `set PYTHONPATH=list;of;paths`.

To set this variable from PowerShell, use: `$env:PYTHONPATH=’list;of;paths’` just before you launch Python.

Setting this variable globally through the Environment Variables settings is **not** recommended, as it may be used by any version of Python instead of the one that you intend to use. Read more in [the Python on Windows FAQ docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/python/faqs).

Answer (score 12):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/Modules")
print sys.path
```

This won't persist over reboots or get translated to other files. It is however great if you don't want to make a permanent modification to your system.

Comment: +1 for the ability to set paths are run time. while arguably "hacky", when writing a proof of concept or a one-off job, this is perfect and leaves the system unmodified.

Comment: I disagree that you only have to do this once. I find that the extra path does not persist past the kernal restarting

Answer (score 12):

This question needs a proper answer:

## Just use the standard package `site`, which was made for this job!

and here is how (plagiating [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17811151/2375855) to my own question on the very same topic):

---

1. Open a Python prompt and type

```
>>> import site
>>> site.USER_SITE
'C:\\Users\\ojdo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages'
...
```

(Alternatively, call `python -m site --user-site` for the same effect.)

2. Create this folder if it does not exist yet:

```
...
>>> import os
>>> os.makedirs(site.USER_SITE)
...
```

(Or, in Bash, your preferred variant of `makedirs -p $(python -m site --user-site)`.)

3. Create a file `sitecustomize.py` (with exactly this filename, or it won't work) in this folder containing the content of `FIND_MY_PACKAGES`, either manually or using something like the following code. Of course, you have to change `C:\My_Projects` to the correct path to your custom import location.

```
...
>>> FIND_MY_PACKAGES = """
import site
site.addsitedir(r'C:\My_Projects')
"""
>>> filename = os.path.join(site.USER_SITE, 'sitecustomize.py')
>>> with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
...     print(FIND_MY_PACKAGES, file=outfile)
```

And the next time you start Python, `C:\My_Projects`  is present in your `sys.path`, without having to touch system-wide settings. Bonus: the above steps work on Linux, too!

---

#### Why does this work?

From the [documentation of standard library package `site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#):

> [Then] an attempt is made to import a module named `sitecustomize`, which can perform arbitrary site-specific customizations. [...].

So if you create a module named `sitecustomize` anywhere in PYTHONPATH, package site will execute it at Python startup. And by calling `site.addsitedir`, the `sys.path` can be safely extended to your liking.

Comment: This is the way to go it seems. A good, cross-platform and long term solution. Great one!

Comment: Many thanks for this, this is the only way I've found to make this work for VS Community 2019!

Comment: I followed all the steps,It works, but I must launch sitecustomize.py every time.

Comment: @JackGriffin: which file have you placed where? I just verified the steps in Windows 10 under Python 3.8.8. Inside my "My_Projects" folder, I placed a `dummypackage.py` with a function definition. And within a fresh (I)Python shell, `import dummypackage` succeeds immediately, without manual intervention. Check variable `site.USER_SITE_ENABLED` (must be `True`); maybe it is disabled in your environment.

Comment: @ojdo: I have Python 3.9.5 on Kubuntu 21.04.The folder I want to 'be public', so to speak, contains a **filebox.py** file.  
I followed your instructions, got site.USERSITE path, created **customizesite.py** there, added the folder as you wrote.Launched customize.py.
The folder is in sys.path.**>>>import filebox** : no errors.
Closed python prompt and launched it again.The folder is no more in sys.path.
In the console, if folder path is the working directory **>>> import filebox** works.
Otherwise I got a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filebox'.

Comment: There is no **site.USER_SITE_ENABLED** on my system, but one **site.ENABLE_USER_SITE**.Guess they change it in this version.Its value is True.You stated that this works on Linux too.It does, but it's only temporary, at least on my system.

Comment: I just verified the steps above on Linux (EndeavourOS, Python 3.9.9, but that should not make any difference). Please note that the file `sitecustomize.py` must be placed in the directory indicated by `site.USER_SITE`! Whatever code you place in there will be executed. To verify that the file was executed, you can check the contents of `sys.path`. I find the `.../my_projects` path appended to this list in each (I)Python session. You don't use any virtual environments, do you?

Comment: @JackGriffin: the filename must be exactly `sitecustomize.py` (or `usercustomize.py`), but not anything else.

Comment: @ojdo in the previous comment I wrote the name incorrectly.The file I created is actually `sitecustomize.py`.I appreciate your help.Will try again all ASAP.

Comment: @JackGriffin, ok, then it is puzzling to me as to why these steps do not work for you. I have been using them since 2015 on various Windows and Linux environments without issue.

Answer (score 6):

In **Python 3.4** on windows it worked when I added it to **PATH enviroment variable** instead of PYTHONPATH. Like if you have installed Python 3.4 in D:\Programming\Python34 then add this at the end of your PATH environment variable

```
;D:\Programming\Python34
```

Close and reopen command prompt and execute 'python'. It will open the python shell. This also fixed my Sublime 3 issue of *'python is not recognized as an internal or external command'*.

Comment: Yeah, this was the only solution to me (Python 3.x). I really have no idea why %PYTHONPATH% isn't resolved on Path parameter. Call the Scripts' folder wasn't  necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The python 2.X paths can be set from few of the above instructions.
Python 3 by default will be installed in 
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\
So this path has to be added to Path variable in windows environment.

Answer (score 5):

To augment PYTHONPATH, run regedit and navigate to KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore and then select the folder for the python
version you wish to use. Inside this is a folder labelled PythonPath,
with one entry that specifies the paths where the default install
stores modules. Right-click on PythonPath and choose to create a new
key. You may want to name the key after the project whose module
locations it will specify; this way, you can easily compartmentalize
and track your path modifications.

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I got it worked in **Windows 10** by following below steps.

Under environment variables, you should only add it under PATH of "**System Variables**" and not under "**User Variables**". This is a great confusion and eats time if we miss it.

Also, just try to navigate to the path where you got Python installed in your machine and add it to PATH. This just works and no need to add any other thing in my case.I added just below path and it worked.

> C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32

***Most important*, close command prompt, re-open and then re-try typing "python" to see the version details.** You need to restart command prompt to see the version after setting up the path in environment variables.

After restarting, you should be able **to see the python prompt** and below info when typing python in command prompt:

[image: On typing python in command prompt]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone trying to achieve this with Python 3.3+, the Windows installer now includes an option to add python.exe to the system search path. Read more in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable).

Answer (score 2):

This `PYTHONPATH` variable needs to be set for `ArcPY` when ArcGIS Desktop is installed.

`PYTHONPATH=C:\arcgis\bin` (your ArcGIS home bin)

For some reason it never was set when I used the installer on a Windows 7 32-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but this is how you add the path to the Windows Environment Variables.

1. Go to the Environment Variables tab, you do this by pressing Windows key + Pausa inter.
2. Go to Advanced System Settings.
3. Click on Environment Variables.
4. On the lower window search for the 'Path' value.
5. Select it
6. Click on Edit
7. In the end of the line add your instalation folder and the route to 'Scripts' folder.
8. Click ok, aceptar etc.

You're done, enter cmd and write python from any location of your drive, it should enter the Python program.

Example with my pc (I have `Python34`)

```
EXISTING_LINES;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts\
```

Hope it helps.

Greetings from Bogotá

Comment: It is indeed a little late, since this answer was already provided five years ago :-) It's also not really what is asked here (since the question is about PYTHONPATH, not PATH)...

Comment: What is Pausa inter.?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the path variable for easily by command prompt.

1. Open run and write  cmd
2. In the command window write the following:
   set path=%path%;C:\python36
3. press enter.
4. to check write python and enter. You will see the python version as shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While this question is about the 'real' Python, it did come up in a websearch for 'Iron Python PYTHONPATH'. For Iron Python users as confused as I was: It turns out that Iron Python looks for an environment variable called `IRONPYTHONPATH`.

Linux/Mac/POSIX users: Don't forget that not only does Windows use `\` as path separators, but it also uses `;` as path delimiters, not `:`.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure Python can find code based on the directory you are executing this code from, if not already there, add to your system environment variable: key `PYTHONPATH`, value `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding a path, its necessary to do some debugging, what path already exists.

Let's say you have to execute `python src/main.py`

Put the below lines in main.py file and notice what paths python interpreter is looking at:

```
import sys
print("paths are", sys.path)
```

If you don't find the path that you need and want to add your path. Follow the below suggestions.

1. First take note of what PYTHONPATH is already there. This is important if something goes terribly wrong.
   `echo %PYTHONPATH%`
2. Set a temporary python path. Make sure to use CMD and not powershell.

   `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Users\mentorconnect\`
3. Start new terminal, start virtual environment and check if sys.path worked?