# Python correctness (i.e., lint) analyzing for Notepad++

Tags: python, ide, notepad++, pylint, pychecker

Does anyone know of anything like [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) or [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) for notepad++? Or perhaps how to use pylint in notepad++.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you install the [Python Script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/index.html), then you can add a new script with the following lines to get pretty good results:

```
console.show()
console.clear()
console.run('cmd.exe /c '
            + 'C:\\Python26\\Scripts\\pylint.bat --reports=n -f parseable '
            + '"%s"' % notepad.getCurrentFilename())
```

The output will include hyperlinks to the lines with the errors/warnings (if the filenames don't have spaces in them...)

Comment: As getting from the above link to the actual download is somewhat torturous, here is a direct link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/

Comment: You have to install Pylint first though.

Comment: isn't it in plugin manager? then just install it from notepad++: *menu>plugins>plugin manager*

Answer (score 3):

The option **"-f parseable" is deprecated** in the current version of Pylint.

The current equivalent alternative is:

```
console.run('cmd.exe /c '
        + 'C:\\Python26\\Scripts\\pylint.bat --reports=n '
        + '--msg-template="%s" %s' 
        % ( '{path}:{line}: {msg_id}({symbol}), {obj} {msg}', notepad.getCurrentFilename()))
```

Note: python path can be different e.g. `C:\\Python27.`

Note2: double quotes in `--msg-template="..."` are important

Answer (score 1):

You could install PyLint using `python -m pip install pylint` and use it via Notepad++'s `Run...` command (<kbd>F5</kbd>):

```
cmd /c python -m pylint "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" & pause
```

To get the output in Notepad++ and link to the code, [use NppExec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36846811/819417).

Comment: can you explain more detailly?

Comment: For most recent software (Windows 10, N++, etc.), what you want is: `cmd /c pylint "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" & pause`.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me, but this does:

1. Install PyLint using `python -m pip install pylint`
2. Install NppExec via the [Plugin Manager](https://gist.github.com/CTimmerman/3fc259d7867c38f6919e), press <kbd>F6</kbd>, and save this script as "PyLint":

   ```
    NPP_SAVE
    cd "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
    env_set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
    python -u -m pylint "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
   ```

Sample output:

```
NPP_SAVE: C:\Users\Cees\Documents\http_ear.py
CD: C:\Users\Cees\Documents\http_ear.py
Current directory: C:\Users\Cees\Documents
ENV_SET: PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
$(SYS.PYTHONIOENCODING) = utf-8
python -u -m pylint "C:\Users\Cees\Documents\http_ear.py"
Process started (PID=25136) >>>
************* Module http_ear
http_ear.py:16:0: C0301: Line too long (1780/100) (line-too-long)
http_ear.py:17:0: C0301: Line too long (226/100) (line-too-long)
http_ear.py:26:0: C0304: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 8.00/10 (previous run: 8.00/10, +0.00)

<<< Process finished (PID=25136). (Exit code 16)
================ READY ================
```

You can link the bug locations using NppExec's Console Output Filters. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and enable this filter with Red set to `FF`:

```
%FILE%:%LINE%:%CHAR%
```

Then double clicking a red line focuses the specified location in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Executable instead of the Batch if you want to use Pylint within NotePad++.

Go to the Configuration from Python Script and create a new .py File to run Pylint from that. (*i called my file npphelper.py*)
(*Add that npphelper.py to Menu-items and Toolbar-icons, then you can execute it by pressing a Button.*)

This will run Pylint into Notepad++, i splitted the Command into 2 Parts:

```
pyLint = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python35\\Scripts\\pylint.exe --reports=n'
console.show()
console.clear()
console.run('%s "%s"' % (pyLint, notepad.getCurrentFilename()))
```

1. Path to pylint.exe (*i used a Shortname instead of Doublequotes*)
2. The File you want to check with Pylint (*actualy returns the Path from active Tab*)

(*You have to change the Paths so that it fits to your Installation...*)

All you have to do now is saving this npphelper.py, open the Tab with your Project-File and run the npphelper.py you created for pylint. (*e.g. via button*)

---

If you don't want to use the default Configuration then generate a pylintrc Template (*save them where you want*). I've done it via CMD with the following Command:

```
pylint.exe --generate-rcfile>>myfilename.pylintrc
```

Then you need to change some lines into the npphelper.py:

```
rcfile = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python35\\Scripts\\myrcfile.pylintrc'
pyLint = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Python35\\Scripts\\pylint.exe --reports=n --rcfile="%s"' % rcfile
console.show()
console.clear()
console.run('%s "%s"' % (pyLint, notepad.getCurrentFilename()))
```

---

I've installed Python Script 1.0.8.0 with all the Extras using the .msi File [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%201.0.8.0/).
(*Using the PluginManager in Notepad++ gives you version 1.0.6.0 instead of 1.0.8.0*)

I use Windows 7 with Notepad++ 6.9.1, Python 3.5.1 and Pylint 1.5.5.
(*i installed pylint via CMD -> "[pip install pylint](https://www.pylint.org/#install)" and updated it.*)

---

Some more usefull Links:

- [How do I create a pylintrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448731/how-do-i-create-a-pylintrc-file)
- [PyLint “Unable to import” error - how to set PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath)