# How do I create a pylintrc file

Tags: pylint

I am running linux. Can I do something like `pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc` and then make changes to the resulting `.pylintrc` file to override the default settings? And if so should it be in my `~/` directory or should I put it in .pylint.d?

Answer (score 199):

You may put it in:

- `/etc/pylintrc` for default global configuration
- `~/.pylintrc` for default user configuration
- `<your project>/pylintrc` for default project configuration (used when you'll run `pylint <your project>`)
- wherever you want, then use `pylint --rcfile=<wherever I want>`

Also notice when generating the rc file, you may add option on the command line before the `--generate-rcfile`, they will be considered in the generated file.

Comment: I recommend against a system-wide or user-wide rc file. It is almost always good to have it per project, and saved in version control.

Comment: IMO it doesn't hurt to have a user-wide rc file with the user's default settings, and have additional project-specific rc files where that is necessary for a project (still, +1 for your comment).

Comment: You may also set the $PYLINTRC environment variable, pointing to your configuration file's location.

Comment: Where do these go on windows?

Comment: `.pylintrc` in a project directory also gets picked up by default if `pylintrc` does not exist. http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html?highlight=pylintrc#command-line-options

Comment: @Elliot you run 'pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc' in your directory where your python program is situated. Make changes in the .pylintrc file after opening it in the notepad++, save the changes and run the python program in that directory. It works. However, I was looking for a solution that will implement this change in the global scope and not just in the directory. If you find that please let me know.

Comment: I want to know where to put .pylintrc file for its application in global scope in windows. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Elliot Look at the following answer 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372295/how-to-specify-a-configuration-file-for-pylint-under-windows

Comment: `https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html#command-line-options` scroll down a little for `pylintrc` locations

Comment: Vote down because of the missing link to the official documentation.

Answer (score 150):

According to documentation [here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-find-the-name-corresponding-to-a-specific-command-line-option), we can use the following command to generate a pylint rc file with all its options present:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > ${HOME}/.pylintrc
```

The above command will create the file `.pylintrc` under your home directory. Then you can tweak the rc file to fit your needs.

Comment: I think you mean `pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc`. `~` means `$HOME`

Comment: yeah, `~` means $HOME in Linux. Maybe I should change it to `$HOME` to be more explicit.

Comment: better `${HOME}` since is a `shell parameter expansion` ‣ https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748880/3889948 and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: the example command to generate the rc file no longer appears in the faq, it now appears in [this page](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

There's a 'new experimental feature' to interactively generate a .pylintrc file.

```
pylint-config generate --interactive

Please choose the format of configuration, (T)oml or (I)ni (.cfg): T
Do you want a minimal configuration without comments or default values? (y)es or (n)o: n
Do you want to write the output to a file? (y)es or (n)o: y
What should the file be called: .pylintrc
Wrote configuration file to ~/.pylintrc
```

And as far as I can tell in the docs there isn't an obvious way to choose a config file, so prob best to put it in `~/` as previously suggested.

Hope that helps!