# pylint 1.4 reports E1101(no-member) on all C extensions

Tags: python, pylint, python-extensions

We've been long-time fans of `pylint`. Its static analysis has become a critical part of all our python projects and has saved tons of time chasing obscure bugs.  But after upgrading from 1.3 -> 1.4, almost all compiled c extensions result in E1101(no-member) errors.

Projects that previously run perfectly clean through `pylint` 1.3 now complain about almost every C extension member with E1101. We've been forced to disable E1101 errors, but this materially detracts from the usefulness of `pylint`.

For example, this perfectly valid use of the `lxml` package

```
r"""valid.py: demonstrate pylint 1.4 error"""
from lxml import etree
print etree.Element('mydoc')
```

Run this through `pylint`, and it reports:

```
$ pylint -rn valid.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module valid
E:  3, 6: Module 'lxml.etree' has no 'Element' member (no-member)
```

But it is perfectly valid:

```
$ python valid.py
<Element mydoc at 7fddf67b1ba8>
```

Here's where it gets really weird. A very small handful of C extensions seem to work just fine through `pylint`, e.g.:

```
r"""valid2.py: this one works fine"""
import sqlite3
print sqlite3.version

$ pylint -rn valid2.py
No config file found, using default configuration
```

My question is, has anyone else witnessed this? And if so, would you be willing to share your workaround/solution?

We've experimented with trying to create plugins to suppress these warnings
(http://docs.pylint.org/plugins.html#enter-plugin), but we're having difficulty making heads or tails of the docs -- and the `astroid` base class is uber-complex and has defied our attempts to grok it.

For real bonus points (and our eternal gratitude) we'd love to understand what changed in `pylint`.  We'd be happy to fix the code (or at least publish a best practice document for C extension authors) that would satisfy `pylint`.

Platform details

```
$ pylint --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.4.0,
astroid 1.3.2, common 0.63.2
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul  1 2013, 18:09:11)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Shortly after posting my question, I found the answer.  The change was in fact done on purpose as a security measure.  Pylint imports modules to effectively identify valid methods and attributes. It was decided that importing c extensions that are not part of the python stdlib is a security risk and could introduce malicious code.

This was done in the release of Astroid 1.3.1  https://mail.python.org/pipermail/code-quality/2014-November/000394.html

> Only C extensions from trusted sources (the standard library) are
>   loaded into the examining Python process to build an AST from the live
>   module.

There are four solutions if you want to use pylint on projects that import non-stdlib c extensions.

1) Disable safety using the `--unsafe-load-any-extension=y` command line option. This feature is undocumented and classified as a hidden option (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/code-quality/2014-November/000439.html).

2) Disable safety using the `pylint.rc` setting `unsafe-load-any-extensions=yes`.  This is recommended over option 1 and includes full documentation in the default pylint.rc file (created with `--generate-rcfile`).

3) Specifically list packages or modules names that you trust to be loaded by pylint in the `pylint.rc` file using the `extension-pkg-whitelist=` option.

4) Create a plugin to manipulate the AST (I have no idea how to effect this -- but it's regularly discussed on on the pylint mailing list).

We opted for Option 3. We added the following line to our project `pylint.rc` file:

```
extension-pkg-whitelist=lxml
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to note, however, that option 3 unfortunately doesn't seem to work with some STL packages, e.g., `multiprocessing`.

Comment: For #4, this documentation seems to directly address how to fix false positive `no-member`s - http://docs.pylint.org/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Updated link: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html

Comment: @SpainTrain sorry but link is dead again.

Comment: https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/plugins.html I think they no longer do the `latest` redirection.  Thanks again for pointing out (again X-D).

Comment: Here's the latest link: https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.8/how_tos/transform_plugins.html

Comment: Even better link to latest docs:  https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_tos/transform_plugins.html

Comment: See also: [How do I create a pylintrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22448731/3357935)

Comment: It's now called `extension-pkg-allow-list`

Comment: I had to add it like `extension-pkg-allow-list=lxml,` (comma) for some reason, on`pylint 2.13.9`, `Python 3.6.8`, `CentOS 7`.

Answer (score 8):

@user590028, thanks a lot for your answer! I just ran into this same problem with the libraries win32api, win32evtlog, win32file, win32gui, and win32process, and your solution worked.

I used another method I think is worth posting here, which is to call pylint and pass the whitelisted packages as a parameter:

```
pylint --extension-pkg-whitelist=win32api,win32evtlog,win32file,win32gui,win32process myfile.py
```

Comment: Your quite welcome.  fyi -- the `extension-pkg-whitelist` was option 3, and the same one we opted for.

Comment: I just want to make sure people know you can pass it as a command-line parameter to pylint as well.

Answer (score 5):

For those of you using VS Code, it's a bit tricky to find where to put the command as I couldn't find my executable.

In VS Code;

1. click on File > Preferences > Settings.
2. Scroll down to "Python Configurations" in the left window
3. scroll down to "Python Linting: Mypy Args" in the right window
4. click on "Edit in settings.json" link
5. edit the json to include:
       "--extension-pkg-whitelist="

I had to do all this because PyLint isn't executable from my Windows command line...

Comment: I was able to use the command line argument in VS Code for pylint by editing the user settings file to include this line:
```"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--unsafe-load-any-extension=y"],```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS Code for Mac, this is what you need to do in order to edit the settings.json file:

1. Click on Code (i.e. the Visual Studio Code tab which is on the left of the 'File' tab) -> Preferences - > Settings
2. Scroll down to Extensions and click on Python in the list.
3. Click on any of the `Edit in settings.json` links. This opens up `settings.json` for editing.
4. Add the line `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["----extension-pkg-whitelist=1xml"]`.

Comment: here, it goes to `{… "pylint.args": […, --extension-pkg-allow-list=posix_ipc ]}`