# Visual Studio Code pylint: Error when all is ok

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

Why I get this message in VCCode but actually there are no errors?

[image: error]

And this one

[image: MissingMoodule]

If I run the program it's working without errors.

Comment: If linting error is reproducible outside of VS Code, please open up an issue on Pylint's GitHub: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski, I figured it out. It's same as discribed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437071/pylint-1-4-reports-e1101no-member-on-all-c-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the pylint whether used by python files or not as below:

- Go to settings in VS Code
- search for 'pylint'
- you can find the below checkbox in 'Python › Linting: Pylint Enabled'
  **Whether to lint Python files using pylint.**
- Just uncheck that ( No need to restart the VS Code)

Answer (score -1):

As I understand:

1) pylint can't recognize `init()` method because his description in compiled `paygame.base` module. The tooltip with docstring about pygame was showed by Intellisense from Python extension. I do not know where Intellisense gets it from.

2) It's not an error. It's Intellisense shows declare of `display` from **init**.py from pygame module: "display = MissingModule("display", geterror(), 1)"

P.S.: I am new to python and visual studio code. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: More correctly described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437071/pylint-1-4-reports-e1101no-member-on-all-c-extensions

Answer (score -1):

Perfect Solution!

Steps to remove pylint warning/errors:

- Click settings icon at the bottom left on your VS Code
- Go to Settings
- Type 'pylint' in the search section
- Click edit icon and Set the following attribute - (Initially it would set to true)

> "python.linting.enabled": false,