# Problems with PyGame in VS code and possible false error alerts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to learn pygame and am having trouble getting it to work. (I'm using python 3.8.5 64 bit) First I installed pygame with `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user` and that worked fine and I could type `import pygame` with no errors. The next line, `pygame.init()`, gave me an error though. The error was `Module 'pygame' has no 'init' memberpylint(no-member).` I went to this link for a solution [Why does it say that module pygame has no init member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569453/why-does-it-say-that-module-pygame-has-no-init-member.) And found one which was to paste `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=lxml"]` into `.vscode>settings.json` but this didn't make the errors go away (yes I saved both files). The real confusing part to me though is that the code works how I want it to (to make a new, blank window for the game and close with the red x in the top right) even with these errors. I think every time I call a method from pygame I get an error even if the methods working and I just want to make sure leaving it how it is won't break things in the future.

`print(pygame)` gets me

```
<module 'pygame' from 'C:\\Users\\jgood\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\pygame\\__init__.py'>
```

`dir(pygame)`gets me

```
pygame 1.9.6
```

Finally here is the code

```
#where most python goes

import pygame

#initating our pygame stuff won't work without this line
pygame.init() <--- Module 'pygame' has no 'init' memberpylint(no-member)

#create screen like html document.getelementbyid.ect.ect
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) # this takes two args height and width in pixels

running = True # flag

#game loop
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: <----- Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' memberpylint(no-member)
            running = False
```

and here is my `settings.json` file

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\jgood\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\python3.8.exe",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=lxml"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a difference between the python interpreter throwing an Exception when you run the code (commonly referred to as an "error") and the warnings that [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) is showing you.

pylint's job is to try to warn you about potential issues prior to running your code. It's a static analysis library that tries to infer potential problems. One thing it sometimes has trouble with is detecting "members" for complex or dynamic packages. Pygame is such a package.

The warnings its giving you here are telling you that pylint thinks there's no `init()` function in pygame. There is, it's just that pylint can't see it with its code analysis. You can handle this in several ways:

- you can fully disable pylint for pygame
- you can disable pylint on a per-line basis
- you can disable pylint on a per-block basis
- you can disable pylint on a per-line/per-block basis specific to a particular warning

You can read about the various options for [suppressing pylint warnings here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning)

For now I suggest you use the information in the post you linked to -- but notice there's a typo in that author's answer that is corrected in the comments. You'll want to change `["--extension-pkg-whitelist=lxml"]` to read `["--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame"]`