# pylint reports error for pycurl.Curl() which is not correct

Tags: python, pylint

I'm running pylint and get the following error:

```
E: 69, 8: Module 'pycurl' has no 'Curl' member (no-member)
```

However, I can only use the `Curl` function, there is no `curl` function (proven by the script not running if I change to `curl`).

Source code:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: `c = pycurl.Curl()`

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437071/pylint-1-4-reports-e1101no-member-on-all-c-extensions).

Comment: Thanks @DYZ, that's a good read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running pylint with `--extension-pkg-whitelist=pycurl`? The reason for getting such errors on modules like pycurl is that these modules are sometimes C modules, which pylint cannot understand statically without effort tailored for each module in particular (for instance pylint has special support for numpy and the likes). When you pass it `--extension-pkg-whitelist`, you notify pylint to import that module in order to built an AST from the live object, which in most cases leads to the false positive being suppressed.

Comment: This worked! From the documentation I also read that by using this parameter..."(C) Extensions are loading into the active Python interpreter and may run arbitrary code", which is a helpful comment.