# Pylint e1101: Class 'reddit' has no 'subreddit' member

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py, praw

I am trying to get a random image from the top 10 posts on the "memes" Reddit subreddit, but it's giving a E1101 pylint error. I seem to have done everything correctly. Here is my code:

I cant seem to find anything on this.

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='my client ID',
    client_secret='my client secret',
    user_agent='my user agent',
    username='username')




@commands.command()
async def meme(self):
    memes = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes if not x.stickied)
```

Comment: Can you point out which line is the linter throwing that msg?

Comment: If a class uses `setattr` to create attributes at runtime, Pylint can't detect those.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/35990313/494134

Comment: @ThuYeinTun 
    memes = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
reddit specifically

Comment: [Here's the line where `Reddit.subreddit` is defined](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/master/praw/reddit.py#L222).  I would expect your linter to see that.  Are your `praw` and `pylint` installations both their most recent versions?

Comment: both praw and pylint are updated

Answer (score 1):

That's because pylint by default [only trusts C extensions from the standard library](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/code-quality/2014-November/000394.html) and will ignore those that aren't.

As praw isn't part of stdlib, you have to whitelist it manually. To do this, navigate to the directory of your project in a terminal, and generate an rcfile for pylint:

```
$ pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc
```

Then, open that file and add praw to the whitelist like so:

```
extension-pkg-whitelist=praw
```

After that, all E1101 errors regarding praw shouldn't appear anymore

*[More details in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28442092/2533467)*