# Anaconda VTK 8.2.0 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vtk

I am just starting to use vtk with python.

I use Anaconda + VTK 8.2.0 (installed with Anaconda Navigator)

In VScode I tried the example: https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Cylinder

**Result:** It works, it shows a cylinder.

**Problem:** VScode highlights some 'problems':

No name 'util' in module 'vtk'

Unable to import 'vtk.util.colors'
...

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFvyo.png)

I think it has something to do with the pylint extension, but I don't know how to solve it.

Kind regards,
Kns

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: No, I'm running a clean installation of Anaconda

Comment: Found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52260240/11216179

Comment: Glad to hear that. Maybe you'd consider to formulate an [answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others who encounter the same problem can benefit from it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52260240/11216179 , post of BlakcRece )

In VS Code;

1. click on File > Preferences > Settings.
2. Scroll down to "Python Configurations" in the left window
3. scroll down to "Python Linting: Mypy Args" in the right window
4. click on "Edit in settings.json" link
5. edit the json to include: "--extension-pkg-whitelist=vtk"
6. ( Or if you want to add all libraries: edit the json to include: "--extension-pkg-whitelist=all" )