# Pylint and python

Tags: python, pylint

I want to bind a file containing pylint disable commands into a python file. and run it using pylint command.

like pylint --reports=n filename.py

but how to bind and external file containing(#pylint: disable=(code)) pylint disable command into filename.py

anyone knows please comment your answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a pylintrc file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448731/how-do-i-create-a-pylintrc-file)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a Pylint configuration file:

```
pylint --rcfile=/path/to/config.file
```

then put this in your config file with what commands you want to disable after the "disable=" part:

```
disable=
```