# Pylint giving me "Final new line missing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, lint, pylint, blank-line

Pylint complains on last line where I'm calling function `deletdcmfiles()`. `Final newline missing`. I'm new to python and I'm not sure what is triggering this?

Here is the code of the program:

```
'''
This program will go through all Work subdirectorys in "D:\\Archvies" folder
and delete all DCM files older then three months.
'''
import os.path
import glob
import time

#Create a list of Work directorys in Archive folder
WORKDIR = glob.glob("D:\\Archives\\ASP*\\Work*")
#Variable holds three months of time in seconds
THREEMONTHSOLD = (time.time()) - (90 * 86400)

def deletdcmfiles():
    '''
    This function will go through all Work subdirectorys in "D:\\Archvies" folder
    and delete all DCM files older then three months.
    '''
    #Variable to keep counter of deleted files
    deleted_files = 0
    #Loop through each Work subdirectory and delete all .DCM files older then 3 months
    for mydir in enumerate(WORKDIR):
        #Store all directory files in a list
        dcmfiles = glob.glob(mydir[1] + "\\" + "*.dcm")
        #Compare Modified Date of each DCM file and delete if older then 3 Months
        for file in enumerate(dcmfiles):
            if os.path.getmtime(file[1]) < THREEMONTHSOLD:
                print("Deleted " + file[1] + " " + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file[1])))
                os.remove(file[1])
                deleted_files += 1
    print("Total Files Deleted :" + str(deleted_files))

#Run program
deletdcmfiles()
```

Comment: It expects an additional newline character at the end of the file. It doesn't really have anything to do with the Python code contained in the file.

Comment: Thank you that resolved it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need an empty new line at the end of your file. Just add another <kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the end of the last line and you'll be fine.

Comment: Why is that though?

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this issue and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491581/509868) to a similar question:

> The reason you need at least one newline is that historically some
> tools have problems if the file ends and the last line has text on it
> but does not have a newline at the end of the file. Badly written
> tools can miss processing that last partial line, or even worse can
> read random memory beyond the last line (though that is unlikely to
> happen with tools written in Python it can happen with tools written
> in C).
>
> So you must ensure there is a newline terminating the last non-blank
> line.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below with [Pylint](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint):

> Final newline missingPylint(C0304:missing-final-newline)

Because I didn't add one blank line after the last code `print(math.pi)` as shown below:

```py
1 import math
2
3 print(math.pi)
```

So, I added one blank line after the last code `print(math.pi)` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
1 import math
2
3 print(math.pi)
4
```

In addition, if you add more than one blank lines after the last code as shown below:

```py
1 import math
2
3 print(math.pi)
4
5
```

Then, you get the error below:

> Trailing newlinesPylint(C0305:trailing-newlines)