# Pylint and Fabric context manager

Tags: python, fabric, pylint, contextmanager

I am working in python script (windows located) to remotely execute (another) script in a linux server. I need to change the directory and keep the state for executing the script and after research I found [fabric's help](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fabric-to-automate-administration-tasks-and-deployments#fabric's-helpers-context-managers) could resolve the problem. However it hits pylint error:

```
E1129:Context manager 'generator' doesn't implement __enter__ and __exit__.and
```

Found some comments to this problem like the ones [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/782), however I do not get the point, not sure what is happening and how to resolve. As far as I understood the fabric context manager cd works along with the ["with" statement](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html), many examples look like my code, few people reports a solution for this behaviour, or it is me who is a beginner does not understand. I am using VSCode as IDE, python 3.7 and fabric3. Hope you can help me to clarify what is happening. Thank you!

This is the code I am using now:

```
from fabric.api import cd, run, task, run, env
from fabric.context_managers import cd

env.hosts = ['xxx@server.domain.com:22']
env.password = ['myp@ss']
DIR = 'elfar/elfar'

def go_to_script():
    with cd(DIR):
        run("ls")
```

Comment: Might be Pylint's fault, you can ignore it.

Comment: So need to remove the error? pylint's does not allow me to see any result.

Comment: You are importing an `cd` object twice.

Comment: Thanks for notice that!, just realize as @iBug mentioned, it is Pylint's issue.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that this issue has been around for very long time, it is called ["false positive not-context-manager error"](https://cmiclab.cs.ucl.ac.uk/CMIC/NiftyNet/issues/196). The solution is skip the warning by disabling the not-context-manager pylint check. I achieved it following the steps below:

1. Go to the project folder and [Create a pylintrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448731/how-do-i-create-a-pylintrc-file)

   ```
   pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
   ```
2. Open the file and locate the lines:

   ```
   # --disable=W".
   disable=
   ```
3. Add **not-context-manager** at the end of the list as they did it [here](https://cmiclab.cs.ucl.ac.uk/CMIC/NiftyNet/commit/67d974b67dd48eced95e56cb2fe56e9a3504eaf0)