# Is it possible to ignore one single specific line with pylint, without changes to the source code?

Tags: python, command-line, configuration, pylint, false-positive

[Is it possible to ignore one single specific line with pylint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829236/is-it-possible-to-ignore-one-single-specific-line-with-pylint) has solutions that requires littering source code with comments what is undesirable for me.

Is there way to specify that given instance is false positive in arguments of the pylint command line tool?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to ignore a specific line without changing the source code. However, it is certainly possible to ignore warning types in the `.pylintrc`. Do you have a specific case in mind?

Comment: @ScottSkiles I have a repository with simple programs, each in multiple stages - from simplest possible to final one with more features. I use it during teaching programming. In this specific case I want to suppress one instance of `W0612: Unused variable 'i' (unused-variable)` as it becomes used one step later and it makes no sense to switch from `_` variable name to `i` variable name just to pacify validator. And adding magic comment is unwanted as confusing beginners by weird comments is undesirable.

Comment: I opened issue at github: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2712

Comment: Ok. Just off the top of my head that might be very difficult to do without any modifications to the source code... have you thought about how this might be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to ignore a specific line without changing the source code. However, it is certainly possible to ignore warning types in the `.pylintrc` or at the top of file.

I'd go with the approach of creating a .pylintrc to suit your needs. For example, if you want to completely ignore `W0612: unused-variable` then you can [create a .pylintrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448731/how-do-i-create-a-pylintrc-file) file and add message names to disable as noted in [pytest docs](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/faq.html#what-is-the-format-of-the-configuration-file).

#### .pylintrc

```
disable=unused-variable,
...,
```

Alternatively, you can disable messages on a case by case basis [at the top of the file](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/faq.html#is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-message-for-a-particular-module-only), and just tell your students to ignore it:

#### Top of file

```
# pylint: disable=unused-variable, wildcard-import, method-hidden
# pylint: enable=too-many-lines
```

Comment: Is it possible to ignore given warning just in one file? I want to get rid of just a single false positive, this rule generally makes sense?

Comment: I don't think so. If it is just a single line, I think it is safe to just add it and tell your students to ignore it...