# TypeError: Post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body' in command line while working on query set

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on creating a blog app in Django and while I was making the Query set in cmd I got the following error,

CODE IN CMD:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='mratyunjay')
>>> post = Post(title='Another post',
... slug='another-post',
... body='Post body.',
... author=user)
```

ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\project\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 501, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'
```

admin.py :-

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Post
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ( 'title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status')
    list_filter = ( 'status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ( 'title', 'body' )
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ( 'status', 'publish' )
```

models.py:-

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ( '-publish', )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

ERROR in models.py :-

```
User model imported from django.contrib.auth.models pylint(imported-auth-user) [5,1]
```

I am new to Django and don't know how to resolve the user model, and while creating the query set another error came up. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: You missed the parentheses after `body = models.TextField`.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for reviewing. I have made the changes but I am still getting the same errors as before.

Comment: Which of the two errors?

Comment: have you migrated after field change?

Comment: @PruthviBarot Thanks you for reviewing, I had migrated but the error was in the body field in the models.py file. I had to add a default value to the body field. It worked after that.

Comment: @KlausD. Sir, I have made the migrations but still getting the error in models.py file,
**ERROR :User model imported from django.contrib.auth.models pylint(imported-auth-user) [5,1]**

Comment: That's a pylint thing. It is not relevant to running the code.

Comment: @KlausD. Is there any way I can apply settings to ignore these pylint messages ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448731/how-do-i-create-a-pylintrc-file → `[MESSAGES CONTROL]` → `disable=imported-auth-user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing () with body field in your models.py file. It should look like this.

```
body = models.TextField()
```

After that, run the following commands,

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

Then try writing your code in commandline