# how to tell pylint to ignore certain imports?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm developing software for Windows with Python. I am developing on Linux, and I am using 
Pylint to check my code. 
I can't get rid of the error:

```
F| Unable to import '_winreg'
```

This is obvious - Python on Linux does not have this module.

So, what do I have to put in my .pylintrc to ignore this error?

Thanks in advance, 
Oz

EDIT:

Documentation says:

```
:F0401: *Unable to import %r*
  Used when pylint has been unable to import a module.
```

Now I need to find how to use it ...

Partial solution:

```
pylint --disable=F0401 <filename>
```

I am still looking for a way to do via .pylintrc.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just run into this as well with the following code:

```
 8: if os.name == 'nt':
 9:    import msvcrt
10: else:
11:    import fcntl
```

`pylint` [failed the build](https://travis-ci.org/optiver/ruruki/jobs/157855177) with this error:

```
E:  9, 4: Unable to import 'msvcrt' (import-error)
```

The [solution](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#message-control) is available since `pylint` 0.10:

```
 9:    import msvcrt  # pylint: disable=import-error
```

Answer (score 24):

Question is quite old, but right now you can ignore modules with `.pylintrc` like:

```
ignored-modules=module1,module2,...
```

I've used it to suppress uninstallable modules check with third-party CI tools, and it works just fine.

Comment: I found that this needed to be in the IMPORTS section.

Comment: @greenmatt It's in [TYPECHECK] in my ``.pylintrc``, maybe different version.

Comment: It looks like this was added in 1.2.1, but updated to apply to imports in 1.4.4 (which is when it moved to the [IMPORTS] section.

Comment: You can generate an empty .pylintrc file by `pylint-3 --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc`

Comment: This works for me for exact module names.  The documentation states that "It supports qualified module names, as well as Unix pattern matching.", but when I provide a wildcard name it doesn't seem to work.   Seems there is an open issue: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/8232

Answer (score 10):

A solution that I have seen employed at my workplace, where there is a special module which Pylint can't possibly get at (Python is embedded and this special module is inside the main executable, while pylint is run in a regular Python installation) is to mock it by creating a .py file and putting it in the python path when running pylint (see [PyLint "Unable to import" error - how to set PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath)).

So, you might have a "pylint-fakes" directory containing an empty `_winreg.py` (or if you need to check imported names, not empty but with faked variables).

Comment: Chris, thanks for you suggestion. I actually did the same for a module which is embedded in our work place too. My dummy module contains all the members of the real module. This is also a valid solutions. You get an up vote for that of course :-)

Answer (score 8):

For those who really want to ignore modules, I am putting here my little patch for pylint:
In '/pylint/checkers/imports.py'

```
262     def get_imported_module(self, modnode, importnode, modname):
+263         import sys
+264         ignoreModules = ['_winreg', 'your', 'bogus','module','name']
265         try:        
+266             if sys.platform =='linux2' and modname not in ignoreModules:
267                 return importnode.do_import_module(modname)
268         except astng.InferenceError, ex:
269             if str(ex) != modname:
270                 args = '%r (%s)' % (modname, ex)
```

This little hack does the job better then just ignoring all warnings. Optimally, if I will have the time I will put a patch to do it via the `.pylintrc` file.

Comment: Have you ever found the time to submit that patch?

Comment: It looks like the upcoming release of pylint 1.5.0 will contain a patch like this.

Comment: Which cmd line option would that be, the [`ignored-modules`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#ignored-modules)?