# Pylint - How to print Pylint's sys.path?

Tags: python, pylint, sys.path

I'm attempting to add modules to my Pylint path so they can be imported by using the solution as [seen in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath). Unfortunately, the modules I expect should be available for import after using this solution still don't seem to be there. I want to check if the path's I'm trying to add to Pylint were actually added or not. Is there a simple way to print out the sys.path of Pylint? Thank you much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pylint should use `PYTHONPATH` in the same way as the Python interpreter. If not, it may be considered as a bug and reported as such.

You may want to try `pylint --init-hook 'import sys;print(sys.path)'` to run pylint while displaying its Python path at first.

Comment: `print("\n".join(sys.path))` will improve the readability by writing each path on a separate line.