# Pylint "unable to import" error but works fine with Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, importerror, pylint

The basic structure of my program looks like this:

```
top_dir
__init__.py
readme.rst
    sub_dir
    __init__.py
        sub_sub_dir
        __init__.py
        example_module.py
        sub_sub_dir2
        __init__.py
        module_with_import.py
```

In Pycharm all imports just work fine. For example I use the following import in 'module_with_import.py':

```
from sub_dir.sub_sub_dir.example_module import function
```

However if I run pylint on module_with_import.py I will get the following error:

```
Unable to import 'sub_dir.sub_sub_dir.example_module' (import-error)
```

Does anybody see what's wrong here?

Comment: Does your PyCharm project settings (project structure) has custom settings? PyCharm modifies PYTHONPATH before execution to include all of your source folders in PYTHONPATH environment variable. I guess you try to run PyLint like `pylint module_with_import.py` in `Sub-sub-dir2` as current working dir. Try `pylint Sub-dir/Sub-sub-dir2/module_with_import.py` in `Sub-dir` directory.

Comment: If I change the directory to sub_dir and type pylint sub_dir/sub_sub_dir2/module_with_import.py I'll get the following error: `no module named sub_dir/sub_sub_dir2/module_with_import.py` If I run 'pylint sub_sub_dir2/module_with_import.py' in sub_dir it'll work but with the same results.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error :(.
Meanwhile I've also created a .pylintrc file with the following content:
`[General]
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("home/username/PycharmProjects/top_dir")'`
Unfortunately without success.
BTW: In an older version of my project I don't get this error although it contains the same imports.
Very strange but there's got to be a solution.

Comment: show an actual shell session, not a hypothetical package

Comment: I had a similar issue, and I found a solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914747/2111922).

Answer (score 4):

Module (package) cannot have minus in name. Rename `Sub-dir` to `sub_dir`, `Sub-sub-dir` to `sub_sub_dir` and `Sub-sub-dir2` to `sub_sub_dir2`.

Next read [PEP-8 The Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My bad, my actual packages (modules) don't have any minus in their names. I edited my question.

Comment: The name of my folder containing the python files had minus in it, which led to the error "unable to import pathlib"! Removing those minus signs from name solve the import problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are top_dir and sub_dir named the same thing?  If so, and there are no files to import in the top_dir (just modules housed in that directory), delete the `__init__.py` & `__init__.pyc` files and try again.

Imagine the following case:

```
foo
__init__.py
  foo
  __init__.py
     bar
     __init__.py
     baz.py
```

If your import statement is something like `import foo.bar.baz` or `from foo.bar import baz` and you're running your script from the top level 'foo', importing will fail [because python importing places the current directory in sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).  You either need to tell python that the top level is not a module, or you need to insert the path you want into sys.path.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue by doing the following:

1. Go to your base project
2. Create a .pylintrc file inside your base project
3. Add the following content to .pylintrc file

```
[MASTER]
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("/path/to/virtualenv_or_pipenv/.../Lib/site-packages/")'
```

You can check the Pycharm project settings/preference for the Python Interpreter paths. The Interpreter is Scripts (in case of Windows system), use the Lib folder path instead(/path_to/.../Lib/site-packages/)

Hope this helps.