Pylint Import Error with local modules outside workspace VSCode
I'm trying to get pylint to recognise modules installed outside the workspace in a multi-root workspace. For example, in the worker workspace I want pylint to recognise imports from schemas.
.
├── .vscode
│   └── settings.json
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yml
├── project.code-workspace
├── scripts
│   ├── build_push.sh
│   └── build_venvs.sh
├── shared
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── schemas
│       ├── pyproject.toml
│       └── src
│           └── schemas
├── web_server
│   ├── .vscode
│   │   └── settings.json
│   └── app
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       ├── app
│       │   ├── .web_venv
│       │   ├── main.py
│       │   └── other_folders_and_files
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       └── scripts
│       
│         
└── worker
    ├── .env
    ├── .pylintrc
    ├── .vscode
    │   └── settings.json
    └── app
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── app
        │   ├── .worker_venv
        │   ├── main.py
        │   └── other_folders_and_files
        ├── requirements.txt
        └── scripts


I have tried numerous things none of which have worked. I tried adding the schemas module into the extra path in the .vscode settings like so...
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths":["../schemas/src/schemas"],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["../schemas/src/schemas"],
}

I have tried installing the schemas module into the worker and web virtual environments using pip install -e . in the shared folder with the relevant venv activated.
I have tried creating a .env file with
PYTHONPATH="../shared/schemas/src/schemas"

and then setting python.envFile: "${workspaceFolder}/.env in .vscode/settings.json

You may check if this question helps you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732819/adding-a-path-to-sys-path-in-python-and-pylint as they both targets "pylint recognizing modules outside the workspace".
