# How do I disable pylint unused import error messages in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

How do I disable these error messages from popping up in the problems box in vs code

[image: error messages]

Comment: Don't wildcard import, `from x import *` it can lead to hard to detect issues. Better just to `import x` and then use `x.Name`. If `x` is very large then shorten it with `as` e.g. `import numpy as np`. If there are just a limited number of objects then import them explicitly, e.g. `from x import A, B, C`

Comment: Perhaps, instead of disabling the import errors, you may want to fix them by telling `pylint` where to find your modules. See 
[pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath/3065082#3065082)

Answer (score 61):

As others have said, you can provide a disable argument to disable a specific message.  I wanted to elaborate on that.

1. **Here is the syntax for disabling multiple messages and for providing multiple arguments**, which was not immediately obvious to me from googling it:

   ```
   "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
       "--max-line-length=80",
       "--disable=W0142,W0403,W0613,W0232,R0903,R0913,C0103,R0914,C0304,F0401,W0402,E1101,W0614,C0111,C0301"
   ]
   ```
2. **You stated that you started seeing way more errors once you disabled that one message.**  That actually might make sense according to [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint):

   > Python in Visual Studio code is configured by default to use a set of
   >   linting rules that are friendly to the largest number of Python
   >   developers:
   >
   > - Enable all Error (E) and Fatal (F) messages.
   > - Disable all Convention (C) and Refactor (R) messages.
   > - Disable all Warning (W) messages except the following:
   >
   >   - unreachable (W0101): Unreachable code
   >   - duplicate-key (W0109): Duplicate key %r in dictionary
   >   - unnecessary-semicolon (W0301): Unnecessary semicolon
   >   - global-variable-not-assigned (W0602): Using global for %r but no assignment is done
   >   - unused-variable (W0612): Unused variable %r
   >   - binary-op-exception (W0711): Exception to catch is the result of a binary "%s" operation
   >   - bad-format-string (W1302): Invalid format string
   >   - anomalous-backslash-in-string (W1401): Anomalous backslash in string
   >   - bad-open-mode (W1501): "%s" is not a valid mode for open
   >
   > These rules are applied through the following default arguments passed to Pylint:
   >
   > ```
   > --disable=all
   > --enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode
   > ```
   >
   > These arguments are passed whenever the
   >   `python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers` is set to `true` (the default).
   >   If you specify a value in `pylintArgs` or use a Pylint configuration
   >   file (see the next section), then `pylintUseMinimalCheckers` is
   >   implicitly set to `false`.

   In other words, PyLint is supposedly pretty lax by default in VS Code, only showing you messages for errors and a few hand-picked warnings.  But when you manually set `pylintArgs` to something, `pylintUseMinimalCheckers` is ignored, opening the floodgates to all messages.  That might be why disabling one message resulted in way more messages being shown.  Then again, I'm not sure why you were seeing unused-import messages in the first place since it should have been suppressed by default according to the documentation.
3. **Actually, this currently doesn't work:** `python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": true` (for me, at this particular moment in time, but hopefully it works fine for you, future reader). To get the same effect, I had to manually set `pylintArgs` to the value it was supposed to be setting automatically:

   ```
   "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
       "--disable=all",
       "--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode"
   ]
   ```
4. **BONUS: Here's an explanation of the list of disabled messages I use**, as shown above in point 1.  It's mostly taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/xen/6334976):

   ```
   # Disabled messages
   #    Pointless
   #       W0142 = *args and **kwargs support
   #       W0403 = Relative imports
   #       W0613 = Unused argument
   #       W0232 = Class has no __init__ method
   #       R0903 = Too few public methods
   #       R0913 = Too many arguments
   #       C0103 = Invalid name
   #       R0914 = Too many local variables
   #       C0304 = Final newline missing
   #
   #    PyLint's module importation is unreliable
   #       F0401 = Unable to import module
   #       W0402 = Uses of a deprecated module
   #       E1101 = Module x has no y member
   #
   #    Already an error when wildcard imports are used
   #       W0614 = Unused import from wildcard
   #
   #    Stricter messages that can be disabled until everything else has been fixed
   #       C0111 = Missing docstring
   #       C0301 = Line too long
   ```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Not only do you give the answer to disable warning and error messages, you give a reason why they might be seeing the 500+ messages after disabling them.

Comment: A full list of codes is available here: http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes.

Comment: Try putting `python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": true` **after** the custom pylint settings in your json

Comment: @nonein The file is "settings.json."  To open it, go to File > Preferences > Settings and click the button at the top right that says "Open Settings (JSON)" when you hover over it.

Comment: A more complete list of codes is avaible in official docs: https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html

Comment: The answer is much wider than the question, very useful. Meanwhile in the latest version of VS Code you should not open JSON file, you just need to find 'Pylint Args' in the Settings and add items, line by line.

Answer (score 10):

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0111"
],
```

You can also disable by message type, e.g., `--disable=W`.

A good reference is [www.pylintcode.info](https://www.pylintcode.info/), with a list of message ids and message types.

Comment: it doeesn't seem to work. I see now 500+ warnings that I didn't see before. I think it disables all other arguments. note that pylinArgs was empty before.

Comment: The link is dead. Here's an alternative: http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes

Answer (score 6):

Adding below to lines at the top of the file will remove the error...And make sure is the lines duplicated inside the program if yes remove it.

```
 # pylint: disable=unused-wildcard-import, method-hidden
 # pylint: enable=too-many-lines
```

Reference: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message

Answer (score 3):

In your VS Code Settings (`CTRL+COMMA`)

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=W0614"
],
```

For more ideas: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_commandline-arguments-and-configuration-files

Comment: it doeesn't seem to work anymore. I see now 500+ warnings that I didn't see before. I think it disables all other arguments. note that pylinArgs was empty before.

Comment: The link is broken and the answer duplicates the https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129121/7869636

Answer (score 1):

For the simple test.py, I did not modify setting but only apply to that file I used 
    # pylint: disable=W0614
Put this line on top of the file then pylint automatically recognized it.

This eliminated 100 unused import warnings

You can keep disabling like this

```
# pylint: disable=missing-module-docstring
# pylint: disable=missing-class-docstring
# pylint: disable=missing-function-docstring
# pylint: disable=wildcard-import
# pylint: disable=W0614
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to `settings.json` in your `.vscode` folder.:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0116,C0301,C0303,C0325,W0311,W1202,W1201,W1203,W1309,W0702,C0103,C0415"
    ]
}
```

Where `--disable=XXXX` can be found in official docs: https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, instead of disabling the import errors messages, you may want to fix them by telling `pylint` where to find your modules*.

So, you would add to `settings.json` in your `.vscode` folder:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--init-hook",
        "import sys; sys.path.append('./mysite')",
        "--disable=XYZ"
    ]
}
```

Where

1. `./mysite` should be the path to your root directory (if you're using [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/), this is the container for your project)
2. `XYZ` is a csv list of rules you *actually* want to disable; if you really want, you can [disable import-error](https://vald-phoenix.github.io/pylint-errors/plerr/errors/imports/E0401) by adding `E0401` here

* See more at [pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath/3065082#3065082)

Answer (score 0):

I use `pylint`

`Ctrl+P`: `Python Select Linter` > select `pylint`

### 一. vscode says those warning type

- Unused PrimaryKeyConstraint imported from sqlalchemypylint(`unused-import`)
- Imports from package sqlalchemy are not groupedpylint(`ungrouped-imports`)
- Import "import logging" should be placed at the top of the modulepylint(`wrong-import-position`)
- standard import "import logging" should be placed before "from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String"pylint(`wrong-import-order`)
- Line too long (141/100)pylint(`line-too-long`)
- ...

### 二. ignore those warning type in setting

`Ctrl+P`: WorkSpace Setting JSON

```json
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=wrong-import-order,wrong-import-position,unused-import,ungrouped-imports,line-too-long"
    ],
}
```

---

OR use setting ui

`Ctrl+P`: WorkSpace Setting

search `python.linting.pylintArgs`

`Add Item` OR `edit item` existed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2023 update per the Pylint extension Settings documentation at:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pylint#settings

```
{
  "pylint.args": [
    "--disable=W0614",
  ],
}
```