# VS code shows pylint import errors while 'go to definition' works

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a project structure of:

```
common (folder)
  |- __init__.py
  |- model.py
  |- monitoring.py
     |- class MyLogger
```

on the model.py file i have this line and the following error:
`from common.monitoring import MyLogger`

errors:

```
No name 'monitoring ' in module 'common'    pylint (no-name-in-module).
Unable to import 'common.monitoring'    pylint(import-error).
```

`import monitoring` hits the same errors.

in practice:

1. the code runs smoothly
2. F12 (go to definition) works and goes the MyLogger.

I searched across the web and couldn't find how to configure VS code well to eliminate those errors.

Comment: "Go to definition" has nothing to do with the linter, btw. Do you have pylint installed into the python environment associated with this project?

Comment: I have pylint installed and running. I took this direction and installed Bandit (the first linting tool in the list) - seems to clear all those import errors.. do you know why? can i configure pylint to be working better or just continue with Bandit?

Answer (score 0):

So i found eventually the answer:
[How do I disable pylint unused import error messages in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123470/how-do-i-disable-pylint-unused-import-error-messages-in-vs-code)

Bottom line:
add to the settings.json:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--max-line-length=100",
        "--disable=W0142,W0403,W0613,W0232,R0903,R0913,C0103,R0914,C0304,F0401,W0402,E1101,W0614,C0111,C0301"
    ],
```