# Pylint Import "import routes" should be placed at the top of the module

Tags: python, flask, pylint

I have flask project and the structure of my **init**.py at the highest level is like:

```
import flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

flask_app = flask.Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(flask_app)
...
import routes
from . import models
```

However I have a warning from pylint:

```
Import "import routes" should be placed at the top of the module
```

If I move that import to the top of the module, it fails. So, I would like to avoid that warning, maybe add it to exceptions. Could somebody advice, how to deal with such exceptions?

Comment: "If I move that import to the top of the module, it fails." how does it fail? Please edit your question to include the entire text of the error traceback you get when you try to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid Pylint warnings on VSCode go to 
Preferences > Settings > open any settings.json file and add

```
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--errors-only"
    ],
```

I don't know how to do the same on other editors.

To disable a particular warning remove "--errors-only" and add 
 
`"--disable="` + the warning you want to disable 
 
check
[How do I disable pylint unused import error messages in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123470/how-do-i-disable-pylint-unused-import-error-messages-in-vs-code)
for more info. 
I hope this can help you.

Another way to do it is by appending

```
#pylint: disable=wrong-import-position
```

but obviously, it avoids the warning only for that module

Comment: VSCode. forgot to specify.

Comment: It looks nice, but I would like to hide that particular warning, but continue receiving other types of warnings. Is it possible?

Comment: you can also try to add
`#pylint: disable=wrong-import-position`

Comment: if a solution worked, you should mark that solution as accepter and/or like it, because someone spent his time trying to help you. Also because other people can have the same problem and if there is an accepted solution they can find quickly what they were looking for

Comment: Thank you for help, it works! I added `#pylint: disable=wrong-import-position` and now pylint ignore that warnings in particular module.

Answer (score 0):

A way to provide a narrowly-focused override to Pylint's opinions is to append `# noqa` to the end of the line that Pylint is complaining about. E.g.,

```
from . import models  # noqa
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I tried: `import ics.routes  # noqa`, `import ics.routes  # noqa:wrong-import-position`, but still have warning from pylint. Adding `#pylint: disable=wrong-import-position` at the top of the module works.