# How to define pylance linting arguments in VS Code (something like "python.linting.pylanceArgs")?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, pylance

Until around 3 weeks ago, I'd been using [pylint](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint) for linting my `python`-files in `VS Code`.

Then, I enabled `pylance` replacing `pylint`.
Yet, `pylance` is not listed in the [specific linter-list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_specific-linters) provided by `VS Code`.

Now, `pylance` *doesn't show me unused module imports*. I suspect this is not included in the default linting arguments of `pylance`, so I tried to find out how to modify them akin to the procedure of doing so with `pylint`, such as documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_default-pylint-rules) and implemented like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488818/12298276) (inserted into the `settings.json` - file of the current workspace):

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--max-line-length=80",
    "--disable=W0142,W0403,W0613,W0232,R0903,R0913,C0103,R0914,C0304,F0401,W0402,E1101,W0614,C0111,C0301"
]
```

How can I customize in a similar fashion the linting rules of `pylance`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `python.linting.pylintArgs` setting is for `pylint` only and is not used by `pylance` (as far as I know)

It seems the setting you are looking for is this one `python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides`:

```
{
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportUnusedImport": "information"
    }
}
```

For the list of `pylance` settings you can visit [this page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance#settings-and-customization) and [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/master/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md).

Comment: Thanks! In the last line, you probably meant pylance settings instead of pylint. Also, I'm aware that pylint-args can't be used for pylance, that's why I asked this question in the first place ;)