# Disable specific Pylance linting messages in VS Code settings.json like with "python.linting.pylintArgs"

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint, pylance

When [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) was introduced, I filed a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158096/how-to-define-pylance-linting-arguments-in-vs-code-something-like-python-linti) on how to generally customize Pylance linting. [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance#settings-and-customization), one can find a few ways to customize Pylance, but there is nothing about how to suppress, mute or actually disable certain warnings and errors.

As a recap, with [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) one can specify the following in `VS Code settings.json` to disable a certain error/warning:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0111"
]
```

As for the background, since the [excessive Pylance(reportMissingImports) linting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252074/import-path-to-own-script-could-not-be-resolved-pylance-reportmissingimports) has not been resolved yet and due to project requirements, I've enabled [pylint simultaneously with Pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13315#issuecomment-701913450). Still, these countless Pylance(reportMissingImports) linting errors are annoying and I'd like to silence them completely.

Comment: Today (I have no idea since when), adding `# type: ignore` to the end of those lines flagged MissingImport by Pylance suppresses the error. This is obviously Not Quite Right and may not last.

Comment: To clarify, `# type: ignore` is extremely helpful in cases where the Linter is not advanced enough to see it is wrong.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

1. Find the error-message you want to modify/disable in the [Pylance's Diagnostic Severity Rules](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md) (in my case "reportMissingImports")
2. Modify `settings.json` with `"reportMissingImports": "none"` (see diagnosis reporting levels in [Pylance's Settings and Customization](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance#settings-and-customization))

The entire JSON-code to be inserted into the `settings.json` is:

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none"
}
```

As an aside, if you want to be at least informed about unused imports, you can use:

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportUnusedImport": "information",
    "reportMissingImports": "none"
}
```

---

**PS: regarding the `settings.json` - location**

Along with the global `settings.json` there are also local versions in your VS-Code-projects' parent directories. In the following, example paths are provided based on my Windows 10 - OS:

- global: `C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`
- local: `.vscode/settings.json`

*These local project settings override the global ones, if desired.*

Comment: It works perfectly. Notice that _settings.json_ is located within _./vscode_ folder.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact that there are various `settings.json`s in VS Code, @BrunoL. I added this in a comment below my initial post.