# Visual Studio: disable pylint for specific lines

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to disable pylint just for a range of code lines in VS Code? There's a certain format for a large string I want to preserve to make it more readable, by pylint enforces its own style on save. But I do want it enabled on the rest of the file.

Comment: Pylint *enforces* nothing. And please share the relevant code and the Pylint message.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your suggestions! I found the simplest solution was to switch my formatter to `yapf`, then use `# yapf: disable` and `# yapf: enable`.

Answer (score 0):

VS code does not allow this out of the box. Please see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36797) for some possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable specific linting for a module or function with `# pylint: disable=missing-module-docsting` and re-enable it with `# pylint: enable=missing-module-docsting`. Just replace what the name with the one you are having.

Check: [How do I disable pylint unused import error messages in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123470/how-do-i-disable-pylint-unused-import-error-messages-in-vs-code)