# Is there a way to make pylint import configurations compatible in PyCharm and VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, python-import, pylint

While I run and debug my project in PyCharm, currently using Python 3.10, I also often prefer to edit my code in VS Code. The file structure of my project looks like:

```
my_project_folder
├─ subfolder_1
├─ subfolder_2
├─ …
├─ __init__.py
└─ application.py
```

Import statements in my code look like

```
from subfolder_1 import func1, func2
```

and it works perfectly in PyCharm. However this form of statement raises pylint import error `Unable to import 'subfolder_1'` in VS Code.

At the same time if I change an import statement like

```
from my_project_folder.subfolder_1 import func1, func2
```

it raises no errors in VS Code, but I can not run the project in PyCharm due to the error `Unresolved reference 'my_project_folder'`.

As for now I am not going to work on any new python project, so I did make no special configuration changes (like adding virtual environment, etc.) either in PyCharm or in VS Code.

Is it possible to change configurations in PyCharm and/or VS Code to make any form of import statement acceptable for both of them?

---

UPDATE. As a temporary solution I have just suppressed the disturbing error message in VS Code. It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488818/4007869) why to do this in the right way you should go to Workspace Settings, find 'Pylint Args' and add three items:
`--disable=all`

```
--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode
```

`--disable=F0401`
After this imports that are really wrong are still marked by another color in VS Code color scheme so I can see my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe you can use the `sys.path.append()` method.
>
> ```py
> import sys
> sys.path.append("put_your_path_here")
> ```

---

---

*The original answer was overly simplistic, re-edited as follows:*

First of all you need to know that VS Code uses your currently open folder as the workspace. I created the file structure in your question and opened it in VS Code, they are in the same folder, and importing them like this doesn't give an error.

[image]

So maybe you are opening another folder or there should be other code causing this error.

**about your comment:**

You can import like this at the beginning of your code:

```py
import sys
# Just an example, please modify it according to your file directory
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\New_Test\\my_project_folder\\subfolder_1")

from subfolder_1 import func1, func2
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. I should check why this does not work for me. I guess it's because some pylint arguments are also defined in PyCharm.

Comment: I'm sorry this didn't work for you. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for me to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @JialeDo, the problem is that a certain installation of PyCharm is needed to reproduce the issue completely. At least VS Code behavior changes, when I, say, change the root folder for the corresponding PyCharm's project. After I applied a temporary solution to suppress the annoying messages (see the update above), I am not sure I'll ever investigate the issue further. Anyway I greatly appreciate your efforts and your wish to help me. Thank you!