# pylint import error in vscode even though python executer successfully imports it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am using vscode for coding my python code. I use pandas, numpy and requests library in my code. If I run the code, It works fine. But in VScode editor, in the problems section, always Its says the message as

```
Unable to import 'numpy' (pylint import error)
Unable to import 'pandas' (pylint import error)
Unable to import 'requests' (pylint import error)
```

I searched in StackOverflow questions to find the answer to this problem, It says to install `pandas` using `pip`. I did that also. But still I am facing the same problem. How to fix this problem in vs code editor

Comment: This question is I believe very related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath

Answer (score 14):

This is not telling you that `numpy` or `pandas` is not installed. It is telling you that `pylint` can't verify your `numpy` and `pandas` calls. Most of `numpy` and `pandas` is written in C, not Python.

The `pylint` [documentation](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/technical_reference/c_extensions.html) says

> Linting C extension modules is not supported out of the box,
>   especially since pylint has no way to get an AST object out of the
>   extension module.

So there is no problem with your code, even if VSCode says it is a problem. It is a technical limitation of `pylint`. If it worries you, disable `pylint` message E401 for these `import` statements. Put `#pylint: disable=E401` on the same line as your `import` statement.

Comment: ... or if you want to disable it permanently, you can add `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=E401"]` to your `settings.json`.

Comment: This answers does not seem correct. A correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath

Comment: In my case what worked was to define a new interpreter for python as suggested by  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Please note the error code is `E0401` not E401 (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1185)

Comment: I think this answer is correct in the cause, though you may need to use a different code, either `E0401` (as just mentioned) or in my case `E0611`, since I was doing `from foo import bar` vs. just `import bar`.