# Why im getting an error at importing django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting this error in VS Code:

> error: "Unable to import 'rest_framework'pylint(import-error)"

I've installed djangorestframework with pip in my virtual environment. I activated the environment before installing it but when I try to import django_rest_framework in my app "book", it says that can't import it. I've added the rest framework in my installed apps but I don't know which is the problem.

I'm working with django 2.1.5 and djangorestframework 3.9.3 and python 3.6.7 and pip3 19.1.1
I've checked with pip freeze and it's installed.
The virtual environment is activated.

What could be the problem?
I opened in PyCharm but i got the same error

Code from I'm getting the importation error in my serializer.py file that is in my app called "book"

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Book
from .serializer import BookSerializer
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'book',

]
```

Comment: add full error trackback

Comment: What version of Python is Django using, and for what version of Python did `pip` install the package?

Comment: Are you getting this error in IDE?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath

Comment: Have you installed pylint in the same environment that contains your python packages? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1185

Comment: Have you installed rest_framework using pip or pip3 ? (unless your default pip version is pip3)

Comment: I'm facing same issue but I'm using Docker so no virtual env

Comment: Same issue here for me , pip installation shows success but it did not solve the problem , but it solved when i right click on pycharm error and install using context action

Answer (score 10):

I think you are not using your virtual environment in VSCode. You can update your [workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) like this:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/path/to/your/venv/bin/python",
}
```

Or you can choose [an environment from vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_choosing-an-environment).

Comment: In short,
1. Open VSCode 
2. Press Control+Shift+P 
3. Type Language and Open Configure Language Specific Settings 
4, Add the above mentioned python path configuration

Comment: Just wanted to add, also change: "python.defaultInterpreterPath" : "/path/to/your/venv/bin/python"

Answer (score 1):

Did you install proper package ? The syntax for installing Django Rest Framework is:

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

which is confusing sometimes becouse in INSTALLED_APPS you type 'rest_framewor'. Check if you installed `djangorestframework` not for example: `django-rest-framework`.

Answer (score 1):

I have got almost the same probleme:
**djangorestframework** installed and checked on freeze, rest_framework on **settings.py** and I got the same issue "reportmissingimports".

The solution is to chose **the python interpreter** :

- on VSCode: **CTR** + **SHIFT** + **P**
- then  click on  **Python: Select interpreter**
- then you will got several Python path (ex: Python ('env':venv),Python 3.8 .....   Global, Python 3.8.....)

Answer (score 0):

From a similar experience with `pylint`, try re-creating the virtual environment.
Simply delete the virtual environment directory and re-create it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to chose the python interpreter :

on VSCode: CTR + SHIFT + P
then click on Python: Select interpreter
then you will got several Python path (ex: Python ('env':venv),Python 3.8 ..... Global, Python 3.8.....)
I choose conda one of them and it started working now.