# To ignore pylint(import-error) sometimes is the best solution?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have switched from PyCharm to VSCode for Django development. I cannot get rid of the pylint "Unable to import XXXXX pylint(import-error)" errors for my development modules that are not packaged into my venv.

I have gone through about 20+ discussions from google, most of which are stackoverflow. I have tried all the suggestions and think I now know what the problem is - or at least what the workable solution is.

My setup is as follows. I have a venv where I have pip installed various packages. This is what I use for development work with 2 projects. This works fine and VSCode can see it and use it.

My library code sits in a VSCode project and this can be seen and used from my web project because of:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "/home/XXXXX/.virtualenvs/YYYYY/bin/python",
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/home/XXXXX/dev/VisualStudioCode/repositories/my-library"
]
```

}

So far so good. But after trying all the suggestions for pylint to find this code, I have come to the conclusion that pylint requires my library to be installed in the venv and I don't want to do that while I am still developing. So basically, all my code works fine and pylint works fine for intellisense and debugging. BUT I have to put up with these pylint errors when I have particular files open. Luckily, when I close the relevant file, the pylint error disappears from the problems list in the VSCode terminal.

Has anybody else reached the same working conclusion?

Comment: Try with defining a package from a directory by adding empty `__init__.py` file in it.

Comment: I just tried this. I put an \__init__.py file in my library project folder. Still same pylint error. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: Just disable the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after more google trawling. It's actually in this [[PyLint "Unable to import" error - how to set PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath]) stackoverflow post.

I created the file .pylintrc in my home user folder, and added the lines :

```
[MASTER]
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("/home/XXXXX/dev/VisualStudioCode/repositories/my-library")
```

to this file. PyLint now finds my library code from my website project.

Thanks to Brian M. Hunt, June 2017.