# Why is VSCODE not accepting Python import statements when Pycharm is?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Today, I have updated a code repository and moved around some code/directories. In Pycharm I have debugged it and it's running with no errors (and all imports working). When I open the same project directory in VSCODE it gives me import-errors saying it is unable to import my modules, however it can import the packages. If I retype the exact same import statement in VSCODE, it now works (see image, for reference I have checked with only one statement and it still works). Why does it do this?

[Import statement example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwQYQ.png)

I have tried clearing the caches (using "Clear Editor History" in command palette). As well as putting

`"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}`

in my launch.json

VSCODE: 1.39.2
with Docker, Importmagic and Python extensions.
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Python 3.7.5 in a venv

Can someone suggest how I go about resolving this without having to retype all my import statements. I know it'll be something simple but after a quick search I can't seem to resolve it.

Thanks!

Comment: write to authors of VSCODE. And report it as a bug.

Comment: Are you running under sudo? If so this is a known bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7710.

Answer (score 0):

It was naivety on my part, moving between PyCharm and VSCODE changed my working directory level. And therefore changing the import path to suit fixed it.

And following this answer:

[PyLint "Unable to import" error - how to set PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath)