# PyLint shows "Unable to import" error with app's module file in Django project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pylint

I have an app named "diary" in my Django project:

```
school_diary/
    diary/
        <standart files inside app>
        views.py
        forms.py
```

Inside my `views.py` I make this import:

```
from . import forms
```

PyLint marks it as error. Here's what I have inside my `settings.json`:

```
{
    ...,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "on.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.maxNumberOfProblems": 200,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/alantheknight/Python/Environments/secenv/bin/pylint",
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/alantheknight/Python/Environments/secenv/bin/python3.7",
    ...
```

Also, I read about generating `.pylintrc`, so I ran this command:

```
$ pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
```

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Oh, also I've included `"python.linting.pylint.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-django"]` into my VSCode settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error that most people come across.
You have not installed pylint in the same environment that contains your python packages.
The environment selected in VS Code is displayed at the bottom left on the status bar of VS Code.

Take a look at [stackoverflow/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath).
and also [pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/)