# How to get pylint to import my files correctly using an init-hook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, pylintrc

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39207275/5049813) on how to get pylint to import my files correctly using an `init-hook`.

However, when I run the terminal command `pylint server.py --rcfile=../.pylintrc` I get `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType`. (I assume this is because the part of the `init-hook` that finds the rcfile is somehow failing, but I'm not sure.)

Here's my `.pylintrc` file up to the relevant parts (the rest is just the default template):

```
[MASTER]

# A comma-separated list of package or module names from where C extensions may
# be loaded. Extensions are loading into the active Python interpreter and may
# run arbitrary code.
extension-pkg-whitelist=

# Specify a score threshold to be exceeded before program exits with error.
fail-under=10.0

# Add files or directories to the blacklist. They should be base names, not
# paths.
ignore=CVS

# Add files or directories matching the regex patterns to the blacklist. The
# regex matches against base names, not paths.
ignore-patterns=

# Python code to execute, usually for sys.path manipulation such as
# pygtk.require().
# THIS GIVES THE ERROR
init-hook="from pylint.config import find_pylintrc; import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_pylintrc()))"
# THIS GIVES THE SAME ERROR
# init-hook="import os, sys, pylint; sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pylint.config.PYLINTRC), 'platform'))"
```

**How can I get this init-hook code working correctly?**

Comment: In my environment, similar problem with using .. -- if I give the full path to the rcfile, it works.

Comment: That's a known bug in pylint ([#3838](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3838)). A workaround is to instead use `PYLINTRC=../.pylintrc pylint server.py`.

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3065082

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but I didn't want to use `init-hook` because I had to add absolute paths, so I found a different solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914747/2111922), and I'll include the solution here, but the referenced link contains more context.

- First, I am using `pylint` version `3.0.3` and `find_pylintrc` is not present anymore.
- I didn't want to use absolute paths in `init-root`.
- I wanted to be IDE independent, so tweaking PyCharm configuration is not possible.
- I wanted it to be committed to repository so it had to work for others and can't contain absolute paths.

The solution in my case was to add the following snippet to the `MAIN` section of the `pylintrc` file. (You may have something different than `MAIN` if you are using a different version of `pylint`).

```
[MAIN]
source-roots=repository/apps,src/apps
```

The list of source roots are either absolute or relative to the working folder from where `pylint` is being called, or the project root folder in case `pylint` is called from within the IDE.