# Unable to import pycolors (Pyling import error) Python error

Tags: python, pylint

I am currently trying to import some libraries/modules and everytime I try, it wont work and displays the pylint import error.

Here is what im trying to do:

```
import pycolors
```

I am using pylint, and I don't know how to fix this. I have watched several videos and done a ton of research, but none of them helped.

Comment: Please include the error.

Comment: @Gus Unable to import 'pycolors'. (Pylint import error)

Comment: This error is very generic and specific to your local environment. So, it's difficult to say, but try pip installing pycolors into your local environment again.

Comment: @Slyvick did you see this post when researching the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath

Comment: @Gus just did it again, said it was already satisfied. Still get the same error..

Comment: @Gus and yes, I looked at that but none of it made sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Pylint need to be in an environment where Pycolor is installed in order to not raise a warning . It's not clear whether the problem is when launching with python or analysing with pylint but in both case the solution is to install Pycolor: `pip install Pycolor` (If this is the one you want : https://pypi.org/project/Pycolor/)