# Python Importing Correctly, but Pylint fails

Tags: python, import, package, pylint

I have a python project that looks like this:

```
appname/
   __init__.py
   cli.py
   compute_signature.py
   utils.py
   test/
       __init__.py
       test_compute_signature.py
```

How should I write my imports?
Currently, in `cli.py` I have

```py
from compute_signature import # stuff
from utils import # stuff
```

And when I run `python cli.py` it imports correctly.
However, when I run `pylint cli.py`, it says it's unable to import these modules.
If I change the imports to:

```py
from hex_configuration.compute_signature import # stuff
from hex_configuration.utils import # stuff
```

then pylint succeeds, but actually running the script fails.

What is the correct way to import these files?

Comment: Move cli outside of the modul/app and use
from appname.compute_signature import Foo
Use this also in files inside the modul

Comment: Do any of the methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3065082/6768111) (or other answers in that question thread) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

user2672844's suggestion worked for me.

My structure now looks like this:

```
appname/
   __init__.py
   cli.py
   hex_configuration/
       compute_signature.py
       utils.py
   test/
       __init__.py
       test_compute_signature.py
```

And in `cli.py`, I import like this:

```py
from hex_configuration.compute_signature import # stuff
from hex_configuration.utils import # stuff
```

I guess the main method can't be a part of the module that it wants to import from.