# How do I make a global pylint installation use a local Python interpreter to prevent "Unable to import" errors?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, pipx

I've installed `pylint` using `pipx` so that it is available across all my virtual environments without having to add `pylint` as a dev dependency for each project. I'm also using VS Code and have the following settings to enable `pylint` and point towards the global `pylint` that I've installed with `pipx` in the `.local/` directory.

```json
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "~/.local/bin/pylint",
}
```

The issue I have is that `pylint` import errors are displaying for packages I have installed within the virtual environment, and so I don't know how to link this global `pylint` with the local virtual environment in my project so it can recognise the packages. In VS Code I have the Python interpreter within the virtual environment selected.

I'm guessing that I need to provide some setting to change the Python Path that `pylint` uses to point to the currently active interpreter within VS Code. I'm just not sure whether that setting exists, nor of any workaround. Of course I could just install `pylint` as a development dependency inside my project, but I'd rather just make use of the global `pylint` if possible. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Did you try modifying the python path to add the path of each project ?

Comment: Can the script run correctly when pylint reports an error? Are there any specific tips for wavy lines

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around recently with the exact same setup and experienced the same issue. I followed the hints I had found in some other answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath)), which was to use Pylint's `init-hook` option. So now I have a global `.pylintrc` file in my home folder (i.e. parent folder of all project folders) which contains the following line:

```
[MASTER]
ignore=.venv
init-hook="import sys; from pathlib import Path; sys.path.append(str(next(Path.cwd().glob('.venv/lib/*/site-packages'))))"
```

Naturally, for this to work, the working directory has to be the project's root folder - in VS Code this is most likely the 'workspace directory'. Also, a consistent approach for projects' virtual environments is required, i.e. that the venv resides in the project's `.venv` folder or that there is a `.venv` symlink to the venv's root folder. And also take care that no other Pylint config file takes precedence over the fallback 'global' one, otherwise you'll have to modify that one as well.

In addition, I've just stumbled across a seemingly very pertinent project called [pylint-venv](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-venv/). I haven't had the chance to tinker around with it yet, but you might want to check that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with pylint-venv, and it works.
First, we can install [pylint-venv](https://github.com/jgosmann/pylint-venv/) in the global level (outside the virtual env):

```
pip install pylint-venv
```

Then inside the `pyproject.toml` file for this project, we can configure a init-hook for pylint:

```ini
[tool.pylint.main]
init-hook ="""
try:
  import pylint_venv
except ImportError:
  pass
else:
  pylint_venv.inithook()
"""
```