# Intellij PyCharm/IDEA - pylint.config.find_pylintrc() returns None

Tags: pycharm, pylint, pylintrc

Trying to set Python package path to run pylint as an external tool in IDEA/PyCharm and following [PyLint "Unable to import" error - how to set PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39207275) to setup pylintrc.

> ```
> [MASTER]
> init-hook="from pylint.config import find_pylintrc; import os, sys;  sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_pylintrc()))"
> ```

However, `pylint.config.find_pylintrc()` returns None inside IDEA/PyCharm.

Please advise how to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

You can just download it directly from the pycharm extensions .