# Django and pylintt: inconsistent module reference?

Tags: python, django, pylint

Possibly because of my noobness, I can't get pylint and django management commands to agree about how to import files in my project.

### Setup

```
# venv
cd $(mktemp -d)
virtualenv venv
venv/bin/pip install django pylint pylint-django
# django
venv/bin/django-admin startproject foo
touch foo/__init__.py
touch foo/foo/models.py
# management command
mkdir -p foo/foo/management/commands
touch foo/foo/management/__init__.py
touch foo/foo/management/commands/__init__.py
echo -e "import foo.models\nclass Command:\n  def run_from_argv(self, options):\n    pass" > foo/foo/management/commands/pa.py
# install
perl -pe 's/(INSTALLED_APPS = \[)$/\1 "foo",\n/' -i foo/foo/settings.py
# testing
venv/bin/python foo/manage.py pa
venv/bin/pylint --load-plugins pylint_django --django-settings-module=foo.foo.settings --errors-only foo
```

### Result

You'll note that `manage.py` is happy with `import foo.models`, but `pylint` isn't:

```
************* Module foo.foo.management.commands.pa
foo/foo/management/commands/pa.py:1:0: E0401: Unable to import 'foo.models' (import-error)
foo/foo/management/commands/pa.py:1:0: E0611: No name 'models' in module 'foo' (no-name-in-module)
```

If I change it to `import foo.foo.models`, `pylint` passes but `manage.py` breaks:

```
...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/tmp.YnQCNTrkbX/foo/foo/management/commands/pa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo.foo.models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo.foo'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm upvoting just for the repro script, it's very easy to understand and follow. This is a duplicate, add a `.pylintrc` as described in linked dupe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyLint "Unable to import" error - how to set PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath)

Comment: @SUTerliakov I'm happy to mark it as a dup but I couldn't get the suggested solution to work.

Comment: Hm, interesting, really doesn't work for me on your repro. You can just add `__init__.py` on the topmost level (as a sibling of `venv` and `foo` folders), it resolves the issue. Though there should be some better way.

Comment: @SUTerliakov works. I'm happy to accept that as an answer if you want to submit it

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. Weird.

Comment: is renaming a way to go for you? It looks like the simplest solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, okay, one suggested way was to add `__init__.py` to the topmost folder (though I really dislike this solution, your project folder is not a module). Another working solution is to rename outer `foo` to `bar` - so the trouble source is the name collision. With the help of `.pylintrc` I managed to make `sys.path` equal for both `python foo/manage.py ca` and `pylint --errors-only foo` (just with debug `print`s everywhere). So, it means that `pylint` does some weird lookup not completely equivalent to the lookup of `python` itself, giving precedence to current working directory. `pylint` resolves `foo` to the outer `foo` directory, while python - for inner. For some reason it's changed when `foo` is a part of another module, which doesn't make sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution today, after leaving it for a while.
While it is useless to try and scan the entire project directory, each app inside the directory scans just fine.

My `makefile` line looks like this:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djang.settings.dev venv/bin/pylint djang/*/
```

This includes all app directories inside the project, including the "main" one containing `settings.py`, `url.py` and co.