# How to resolve E0611: No name 'Test_HC' in module 'test' (no-name-in-module)?

Tags: python, pylint

### Context

I have a pip package called `something` with tree structure:

```
src/something/__main__.py
src/something/__init__.py
src/something/hardcoded.py
src/something/bike/ride.py

test/__init__.py
test/bike/test_ride.py
test/Test_HC.py
```

With a class named `Hardcoded_testdata` within the `Test_HC.py`.
And when I run pylint from pre-commit:

```
# Performs static code analysis to check for programming errors.
 - repo: local
   hooks:
     - id: pylint
       name: pylint
       entry: pylint
       language: system
       types: [python]
       args:
         [
          #  "--init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append(\"/home/name/git/something/test/\")'",
           "--init-hook='from pylint.config import find_pylintrc; import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_pylintrc()))'",
          #  "--init-hook='from pylint.config import find_pylintrc; import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_pylintrc()))'"
           "-rn", # Only display messages
           "-sn", # Don't display the score
         ]
       exclude: test/test_files/
```

I get the error:

```
test/bike/test_ridepy:4:0: E0611: No name 'Test_HC' in module 'test' (no-name-in-module)
```

on import:

```py
from test.hardcoded_testdata import TestHC
```

Looking at [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/#files), it seems standard practice to not include the test files in the pip package, hence putting them in a separate folder (named `tests`) at the root of the repository.
Accordingly, I would like to also not pollute my pip package source code with helper files for tests (like `hardcoded_testdata.py`).

### Approaches

The first solution I tried is to "tell pylint to look for the `hardcoded_testdata.py`. So after applying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39207275/7437143) answer like:

```yaml
# Performs static code analysis to check for programming errors.
 - repo: local
   hooks:
     - id: pylint
       name: pylint
       entry: pylint
       language: system
       types: [python]
       args:
         [
          #  "--init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append(\"/home/name/git//something/test/\")'",
           "--init-hook='from pylint.config import find_pylintrc; import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_pylintrc()))'",
          #  "--init-hook='from pylint.config import find_pylintrc; import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_pylintrc()))'"
           "-rn", # Only display messages
           "-sn", # Don't display the score
         ]
       exclude: test/test_files/
```

I still get the error. I even tried hardcoding the filepath (Which is not desirable, because I would like other developers to also be able to work in this project), and that did not work either.

I also included the `__init__.py` file in the `/test/` directory, however, that does not resolve the issue.

When I run `python -m pytest`, it imports the file perfectly fine.

### Question

How can I ensure pylint is able to find the `test/hardcoded_testdata.py` file and/or resolve the E0611 error?

Comment: Put it in `tests/conftest.py` and wrap in a fixture to get rid of import:)

Answer (score 0):

Several changes had to be made to resolve the issue:

- Renamed `test/` to `tests/`, (and refactor the imports accordingly from `from test.Test_HC import ...etc` to `from tests.Test_HC import ...etc` and then the error was resolved.
- Included the tests/conftest.py file as suggested in the comments.
- Added `__init__.py` in all the test directories that contain test files.
- Ensured all test class names were unique.

And in the end, I moved the hardcoded testdata into a fixture, as suggested in the comment, with:

```py
@pytest.fixture  # type:ignore[misc]
def hardcoded_testdata() -> HardcodedTestdata:
    """This is a fixture.

    That means it is an object that can be used as a parameter to a test
    function. It is a way to share data between tests, without having to
    create files that do not adhere to the test_<name>.py naming
    convention.
    """
    hc_testdata: HardcodedTestdata = HardcodedTestdata()

    # Any setup logic can go here
    return hc_testdata  # The fixture provides this data to the tests
```

Which was then used as:

```py
class Test_something(unittest.TestCase):
    """Object used to test something returned
    successfully."""

    # Initialize test object
    @typechecked
    def __init__(  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
        self, hardcoded_testdata: HardcodedTestdata, *args, **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.current_directory: str = os.getcwd()
        self.hardcoded_testdata: HardcodedTestdata=hardcoded_testdata
```