# python: how/where to put a simple library installed in a well-known-place on my computer

Tags: python, import, path

I need to put a python script somewhere on my computer so that in another file I can use it. How do I do this and where do I put it? And where in the python documentation do I learn how to do this? I'm a beginner + don't use python much.

---

library file: MyLib.py put in a well-known place

```
def myfunc():
   ....
```

other file SourceFile.py located elsewhere, doesn't need to know where MyLib.py is:

```
something = MyLib.myfunc()
```

Answer (score 8):

### Option 1:

Put your file at:
`<Wherever your Python is>/Lib/site-packages/myfile.py`

Add this to your code:

```
import myfile
```

Pros: Easy

Cons: Clutters site-packages

### Option 2:

Put your file at:
/Lib/site-packages/mypackage/myfile.py

Create an empty text file called:
`<Wherever your Python is>/Lib/site-packages/mypackage/__init__.py`

Add this to your code:

```
from mypackage import myfile
```

Pros: Reduces clutter in site-packages by keeping your stuff consolidated in a single directory

Cons: Slightly more work; still some clutter in site-packages.  This isn't bad for stable stuff, but may be regarded as inappropriate for development work, and may be impossible if Python is installed on a shared drive

### Option 3

Put your file in any directory you like

Add that directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable

Proceed as with Option 1 or Option 2, except substitute the directory you just created for `<Wherever your Python is>/Lib/site-packages/`

Pros: Keeps development code out of the site-packages directory

Cons: slightly more setup

This is the approach I usually use for development work

Comment: Originally had a typo in Option 2--forgot that SO would interpret underscores as markup.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Excellent analysis of pros and cons.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the [Modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) section of the Python tutorial is a good introduction for beginners on this topic.  It explains how to write your own modules and where to put them, but I'll summarize the answer to your question below:

Your Python installation has a `site-packages` directory; any python file you put in that directory will be available to any script you write.  For example, if you put the file `MyLib.py` in the `site-packages` directory, then in your script you can say

```
import MyLib
something = MyLib.myfunc()
```

If you're not sure where Python is installed, the Stack Overflow question [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) will be helpful to you.

Alternatively, you can modify [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path), which is a list of directories where Python looks for libraries when you use the `import` statement.  Your `site-packages` directory is already in this list, but you can add (or remove) entries yourself.  For example, if you wanted to put your `MyLib.py` file in `/usr/local/pythonModules`, you could say

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/pythonModules")
import MyLib
something = MyLib.myfunc()
```

Finally, you could use the [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable to indicate the directory where your `MyLib.py` is located.

However, I recommend simply placing your `MyLib.py` file in the `site-packages` directory, as described above.

Answer (score 3):

No one has mentioned using [.pth](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) files in site-packages to abstract away the location.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to place your `MyLib.py` somewhere in your load path (this the paths in your `sys.path` variable) and then you'll be able to import it fine. Your code would look like

```
import MyLib
MyLib.myfunc()
```

Generally speaking, you should distribute your packages using [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index) so that they can be easily installed in the proper locations. It would help you as well.

Also, you might not want to install packages in your global Python install. It's customary (and recommended) to use [virtualenv](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/) which you can use to create small isolated Python environments that can hold local packages.

It's best your give the whole thing a shot and then ask further questions if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

The private version, from my `.profile`

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$HOME/lib/python
```

which has a subdirectory "msw" so `import msw.primes` is self documenting or add to a local directory that is already in [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Answer (score 1):

The Python tutorial section 6 talks about modules, and 6.1.2 talks about the PYTHONPATH, which determines where Python will look for modules you try to import.  The tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

In Windows: You can make use of SYMLINK available in W10.

go to <Wherever your Python is>/Lib/site-packages/

```
mklink [your_python_file_name].py <your_lib_folder>/[your_python_file_name].py
```

*tested with python 3.8, 3.10 and 3.11

PROS: You can use multiple python versions

CONS: You have to do this for every version.

*Disclaimer, not intended for production use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).