# How to manually install Python modules in CentOS 5.5?

Tags: python, linux, centos

I have a specific Python module that I wrote that I want to add to my CentOS server. I'm not sure where to add it though...

In Windows, its pretty easy, just drop it in `C:\Python2.X\Lib` or `site-packages` and Python finds it. I'm not sure how to accomplish the same thing in Linux.

Do I need to use yum somehow? Or do I simply have to manually specify the script path before calling the module?

Comment: doh! I mean't to post this on SF... please migrate if necessary. Although I guess technically this is borderline programming related.

Comment: Which Python version? If it is >=2.6, you can copy the packages to `~/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages` (read PEP 370 for details)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clean option: write a [`setup.py`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html), then run that.

The quick option: drop it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.X/site-packages`.

Comment: Is the location similar for python3 as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install the package globally, use this command:

```
$ python -c "import site; print site.getsitepackages()" # Python >= 2.7
```

If you're fine with per-user installation, use this command:

```
$ python -c "import site; print site.getusersitepackages()" # Python >= 2.7
```

This will print the directories that you should put your source in...or even better, check this duplicate's accepted response:

[How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)