# What's the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, package-managers

I'm a bit miffed by the python package installation process. Specifically, what's the difference between packages installed in the dist-packages directory and the site-packages directory?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

`dist-packages` is a Debian-specific convention that is also present in its derivatives, like Ubuntu. Modules are installed to `dist-packages` when they come from the Debian package manager into this location:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Since `easy_install` and `pip` are installed from the package manager, they also use `dist-packages`, but they put packages here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

From the [Debian Python Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Python):

> dist-packages instead of site-packages. Third party Python software
> installed from Debian packages goes into dist-packages, not
> site-packages. This is to reduce conflict between the system Python,
> and any from-source Python build you might install manually.

This means that if you manually compile and install Python interpreter from source, it uses the **`site-packages`** directory. This allows you to keep the two installations separate, especially since Debian and Ubuntu rely on the system version of Python for many system utilities.

Comment: Is this accurate?! I install with pip and it goes to dist-packages. (on Deb Squeeze + Py 2.6)

Comment: It's the same for me too. Packages installed with pip or easy_install all goes into dist-packages.

Comment: Same here, would I have any problems if I remove all those installations?

Comment: Same for me. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Server, and I install most modules with pip, not with apt-get. They all end up in dist-packages, and site-packages is empty.

Comment: @BaselShishani can you confirm the directories are the same for debian? I only checked Ubuntu

Comment: Same directories for Debian 6.0.10 (still on Python 2.6).

Comment: If you use virtualenv with pip, pip will install packages in *site-packages* directory.

Comment: On Debian based systems `pip` and `easy_install` will always install into `dist-packages` because they take the location from Python executable which is built-in value (defined on compilation time). If use `virtualenv` with isolated Python executable this location is re-defined there.

Comment: For me: dist-packages (if virtualenv under Centos Linux) and site-packages (virtualenv under mac OS)

Comment: @BaselShishani seems accurate, maybe the answer was edited to address your (good) issue.

Comment: After `apt install python3-pip` I get a `pip` folder in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

Answer (score 13):

Debian (and Ubuntu) has [introduced](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2009-February/027439.html) its own convention

```
# python3 -m site
```

on Ubuntu Focal gives

```
sys.path = [
    '/qpid-dispatch',
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

The convention, as described in the linked mailing list, is that python deb packages installed by the distribution package manager go into `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and packages installed using `sudo pip3` go into `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`.

If you compile and install your own Python interpreter, it will default to placing itself in `/usr/local`, with `/usr/local/bin/pip3` installs going into `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`.

The point of the Debian convention is to keep the three sets of packages separate:

1. python packages installed by `apt`
2. packages installed by root user with `/usr/bin/pip3`
3. packages installed by root user with their own `/usr/local/bin/pip3`

Answer (score 6):

`dist-packages` is the debian-specific directory where `apt` and friends install their stuff, and `site-packages` is the standard `pip` directory.

The problem is -- what happens when different versions of the same package are present in different directories?

My solution to the problem is to make `dist-packages` a symlink to `site-packages`:

```
for d in $(find $WORKON_HOME -type d -name dist-packages); do
  pushd $d
  cd ..
  if test -d dist-packages/__pycache__; then
    mv -v dist-packages/__pycache__/* site-packages/__pycache__/
    rmdir -v dist-packages/__pycache__
  fi
  mv -v dist-packages/* site-packages/
  rmdir -v dist-packages
  ln -sv site-packages dist-packages
  popd
done
```

(if you are not using gnu tools, remove the `-v` option).

Comment: I'm a little confused which problem you solve with your solution since the question requiers an explanation

Comment: @JürgenK.: the problem for me was which package is used when there are different versions in different directories.

Comment: Is the solution for python packages in one single place. You run it when you do `apt update` on Debian and new python packages get installed in `dist-packages`? You have a `dist-packages cleaner`, go for a patent..

Comment: one more, I have 2 global `dist-packages`: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`, should I make one of it?

Comment: I got it, that is why you use the loop in case there are more folders. Why do you copy `__pycache__` extra using `if`? I would copy it in one go, no need for `if`.

Comment: .. does `rmdir` before `ln` makes sense? If `dist-packages` does not exist, you cannot `ln` or does ln create the linkdir? Wait, according to `man`: `By default, each destination (name  of  new link) should not already exist`