# Are the paths to the python standard library and to the dist-packages different for different linux distributions(Debian, Redhat, Slackware, ...)?

Tags: python, linux, path, linux-distro

My question assumes you are using the same python versions on those different linux distributions. I also exclude virtual environments from my question.

I use the Debian based distribution Ubuntu. There the path to the python standard library (the modules/packages written in python) is `/usr/lib/python2.7`. The path to "external" python packages is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

A system independent way to get these paths is greatly appreciated.

### Edit1

I found:

```
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print get_python_lib()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

and

```
>>> print get_python_lib(standard_lib=True)
/usr/lib/python2.7
```

### Edit2

I think the approach in the first edit is deprecated since I can only find this up and untill the python2.5 docs. The new approach (in 2.7 docs):

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_path_names()
('stdlib', 'platstdlib', 'purelib', 'platlib', 'include', 'scripts', 'data')
>>> print sysconfig.get_path('platlib')
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I haven't found yet how to find `/usr/lib/python2.7` with sysconfig. For now I'll work with the deprecated approach and proceed under the assumption that this yields the desired results.

Comment: Why do you ask—would you like a cross-platform shortcut to these locations?

Comment: *I haven't found yet how to find `/usr/lib/python2.7` with sysconfig.* This should be the path under the `stdlib` key. On 64 bit system this most probably will be `/usr/lib64/python2.7` though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's different, in CentOS 5.6, for example, python external modules are placed in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages`. Actually `dist-packages` is [debian specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages).

Comment: and opensuse will use lib64 (on 64bit)

Answer (score 1):

You can read more into this subject from here 
http://www.aosabook.org/en/packaging.html, $
it talks allot about packaging and library locations if we want to deploy a package to the software repository.

I have talked a little bit about this in my blog, please have a look and give me some feedback

http://insidepython.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/quickintro/

Cheers

Comment: I don't have concerns about packaging(yet), my application uses these paths.