# Python: how to edit an installed package?

Tags: python, pip

I installed some package via `pip install something`. I want to edit the source code for the package `something`. Where is it (on ubuntu 12.04) and how do I make it reload each time I edit the source code and run it?

Currently I am editing the source code, and then running python setup.py again and again, which turns out to be quite a hassle.

Comment: `dpkg-query -L <package_name>` then edit files?

Comment: Ubuntu Generic (and I expect newer versions too) install pip packages to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, and apt packages to /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Answer (score 133):

You should never edit an installed package. Instead, install a forked version of package.

If you need to edit the code frequently, DO NOT install the package via `pip install something` and edit the code in '.../site_packages/...'

Instead, put the source code under a development directory, and install it with

```
$ python setup.py develop
```

or

```
$ pip install -e path/to/SomePackage
```

Or use a vcs at the first place

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/lakshmivyas/hyde.git#egg=hyde
```

Put your changes in a version control system, and tell pip to install it explicitly.

Reference:
[Edit mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)

Comment: I've installed it using `pip install -e /path/SomePackage/`. I navigate inside to this directory's `/src/` and edited a file. However when I run `SomePackage` from terminal it doesn't reflect this change.

Comment: it's where the source code is located, it has the `.py` files which I edited.

Comment: So where is `src`, like `path/to/SomePackage/src`?

Comment: If the package is on pypi, could you tell me the package name and which file you edited?

Comment: it was this package https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns, I git cloned it, and then edited the source code. not `/src/` but `/beeswithmachineguns`

Comment: you should keep the package under source control with something like git.  when you build the package, all the new files that are created will be marked by git and then you can revert changes to all files except for the one you are modifying.  this will force pip to rebuild from scratch instead of rebuilding using the versions of files that were compiled before your changes.

Comment: Is cloning the package a good method or should we `python setup.py` or `pip install it`?

Comment: Just to clarify, we need to re-install each time we make a change to the local version of the source code right?

Comment: **NOTE:** If you use `python setup.py develop` it will install all dependencies in develop mode as well - this is likely not what you need. It will take a lot longer!  However, if you use `pip install -e <path>` it will just make sure the dependencies are all present, and will only run `python setup.py develop` on the current package.

Comment: Is the purpose of putting it in a VCS so that we can simply revert our changes and reinstall the original unmodified package?

Comment: Could someone explain this in a bit more detail?  So I develop my package.  Then I want to publish.  So I fork the package at that point.  Now I have 2 repositories:  The development one and the build/publish one.  I continue to the develop in development.  Now I'm ready to update.  Do I delete the contents of the publish repository and copy in the changes from development, build and push?  If I do that my build repository won't have proper history.  So is my history of commits actually contained in the development repository at the time I forked initially?  confused

Answer (score 13):

You can edit the files installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. Do note that you will have to use `sudo` or become `root`.

The better option would be to use [virtual environment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for your development. Then you can edit the files installed with your permissions inside your virtual environment and only affect the current project.
In this case the files are in `./venv/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`

The path could be `dist-packages` or `site-packages`, you can read more in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388115/9910191)

Note that, as the rest of the people have mentioned, this should only be used sparingly, for small tests or debug, and being sure to revert your changes to prevent issues when upgrading the package.
To properly apply a change to the package (a fix or a new feature) go for the options described in other answers to contribute to the repo or fork it.

Comment: I am using mkvirtualenv, with -no-site-packages option, install pip and install `something`. however I don't see where it installs the file inside the virtualenv that I can edit

Comment: This is ill advice. Editing an installed package directly is seriously discouraged. It makes package upgrade and maintenance a mess. It makes automated deployment a mess. In general it makes devops a mess. See the high-voted answer for proper development practices.

Comment: I just used this approach to quickly debug incoming request in my devops pipeline with a great success :)

Comment: In Fedora 39 a pip installed package can be found in `/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/`.

Comment: In Fedora 39 when installed without sudo it can also be found in `~/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/`

Answer (score 9):

I too needed to change some things inside a package. Taking inspiration from the previous answers, You can do the following.

1. Fork the package/repo to your GitHub
2. clone your forked version and create a new branch of your choice
3. make changes and push code to the new branch on your repository
4. you can easily use `pip install -e git+repositoryurl@branchname`
5. There are certain [things to consider](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1393) if its a private repository

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the custom module that you want hot loading, you can put your running code also inside the module. Then you can use `python -m package.your_running_code`. In this way, you can change the `module` in the package and reflect the result of your running code immediately.