# Install and Import Modified Package

Tags: python

I need to make some changes to the way the OSMnx package gets data from the Overpass API.

To do that, I've forked the repo and cloned that fork into a local directory.

I've made a simple change, adding a print functions to start.

I'm trying to figure out the steps for installing and importing the modified version of the package. I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075397/python-how-to-edit-an-installed-package#23075617)

I'm concerned about a namespace conflict, should I change the name of the folder or the `name` value in the `setup.py`file. I don't want to write over the working version of the package

What file should I point to when installing? `setup.py`, `core.py`, `_init_.py`?

I haven't found any tutorials on how to modify an existing package safely, just stuff on how to make a package from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` will search the installed packages list first, then it will check the directory it was called from for files that match the package it's looking for.

So either using `pip` or `conda` remove the original version of the package being imported.

Then, be sure that the modified version of the package that you want to import is in a sibdirectory of your project directory, and run `import package as xx` and it should load the modified package files.

If it doesn't, it's likely that the package wasn't removed from the right environment.