# remove cpython files in installed packages

Tags: python, pycharm, cpython

I installed a package via pycharm earlier. I made some changes to the package's source code but found that pycharm would still run the old version, and I discovered that pycharm was actually running the cpython compiled .so version instead generated from the old code. Is there a way to force pycharm to rerun cpython or just interpret the source code instead? I tried removing all the cpython .so files but that causes the pycharm to segfault, so I suppose some of those cpython files are actually needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python: how to edit an installed package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075397/python-how-to-edit-an-installed-package)

You ***really*** shouldn't be editing these packages directly, it can easily become a headache down the road. I would recommend following the advice in the above link if you really feel like you need to edit the package, because it keeps you from, well, breaking things.