# PYTHONPATH sys.path difference

Tags: python

I am having trouble adding a directory to my `PYTHONPATH`
The directory is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

When I run

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
```

I can't find it in the result.
Trying things out I noticed the following:
The directory disappears from `sys.path` when `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` is there as a prefix, e.g. the following works fine:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
```

I am not setting `PYTHONPATH` anywhere else, and I checked running it with sudo.

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` isn't **already** in your path? It won't be added to the front if it is already listed.

Comment: It is not. Just checked again one by one.

Comment: What do you get if you run this? `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages python -c 'import sys; print "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" in sys.path'`

Comment: False.  If I misspell python: `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/pythn2.7/dist-packages python -c 'import sys; print "/usr/local/lib/pythn2.7/dist-packages" in sys.path'` True

Comment: I *think* symlinks are also cleared (e.g. Python calls `normpath` on the entries)

Comment: None of the relevant folders appear to be symlinked. Also `python -c 'import os.path; print os.path.normpath("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")'` returns `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why a path may show up. Make sure you don't hit one of these:

- The path must exist, non-existing paths are ignored. From the [`PYTHONPATH` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

  > Non-existent directories are silently ignored.
- Duplicates are removed (the first entry is kept); paths are made absolute (relative to the current working directory) and compared case-insensitively on platforms where this matters.

  So if you have a relative path that comes down to the same absolute path in your `sys.path`, only the first entry is kept.
- After normilization and cleanup, the [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) tries to import `sitecustomize` and `usercustomize` modules. These could manipulate `sys.path` too.

You can take a closer look at your `sys.path` right after cleaning and if there is a `usercustomize` module to be imported by running the `site` module as a command line tool:

```
python -m site
```

It'll print out your `sys.path` in a readable one-line-per-entry format.

Comment: The -S flag disables site. With -S, I can import and use the package. Without it, i.e., with site enabled, the import fails.

Comment: The package that's in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is called `z3`. This works: `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages python -S -c 'import z3'`, and this throws an import error `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages python -S -c 'import site; import z3'`

Comment: @Chris: so either `sitecustomize` or `usercustomize` is doing this, or the `site` module has been customized (IIRC that's the case on Debian and Ubuntu systems, see [What's the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9387928)) with the result that it is being removed.

Comment: It's the site module I have pasted the code from https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/site.py at the top followed by `import z3` and delta debugging it

Comment: @Chris: the Debian / Ubuntu version of that file is certainly different from the version normally distributed with Python.

Comment: I am using the homebrew python version for mac. Ok I got it, it was sitecustomize you were right. My sitecustomize.py has the following code: `sys.path = [ p for p in sys.path if (not p.startswith('/System') and not p.startswith('/usr/local/lib/python') and not (p.startswith('/usr/local/Cellar/python') and p.endswith('site-packages'))) ]`