# How to change python packages directory

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I manually installed Python 2.7.9 with [this file](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tar.xz).

But now, site.getsitepackages() method shows like bellow. And I can't import any installed modules.

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/site-python']
```

The sub-directories must be named  "dist-packages" on Ubuntu instead of "site-packages". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you installed setuptools and pip through apt-get, sitepackages will be installed to the dist-packages directory(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages)).

In this case, the build-in Python and the manually installed Python can have different unicode build settings.

To avoid this conflict problem, I must install setuptools manually through the manually installed Python. Don't use apt-get to install anything related to the Ubuntu build-in Python.

Answer (score 4):

A quick solution would be to rename the directories or create a symbolic link:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: And a lot less headaches.

Comment: I noticed that was not enogh to solve the problem. In that case, a conflict error will occur like "undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromWideChar". It happens because the Python I run with is not the same Python I
built with, and they have different unicode build settings.