# Ubuntu Python "No module named paramiko"

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, paramiko

So I'm trying to use Paramiko on Ubuntu with Python 2.7, but import paramiko causes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

The other questions on this site don't help me since I'm new to Ubuntu.

Here are some important commands that I ran to check stuff:

```
sudo pip install paramiko
pip install paramiko
sudo apt-get install python-paramiko
```

Paramiko did "install".  These are the only commands I used to "install" paramiko.  I'm new to Ubuntu, so if I need to run more commands, lay them on me.

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python

python -c "from pprint import pprint; import sys; pprint(sys.path);"
['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

In the python interpreter, I ran `help("modules")` and Paramiko is not in the list.

two paramiko folders are located in `usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

Comment: Did you try to install it inside a virtualenv?

Comment: @DivakarDass, no, I was hoping to avoid virtualenv since I won't be using Ubuntu for too long, just trying to keep it short and simple.

Comment: Looks like you have a locally-built installation of Python, which is being executed rather than the system-provided one. Try running `/usr/bin/python` instead.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, well, that fixes that, that's interesting.  Thanks!  Is there a way to get the terminal to run the appropriate python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short version: You're mixing Ubuntu's packaged version of Python (`/usr/bin/python`) and a locally built and installed version (`/usr/local/bin/python`).

Long version:

- You used `apt-get install python-paramiko` to install Ubuntu's official Paramiko package to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.
- You used (I assume) Ubuntu's version of `pip`, which installs to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9387928/25507).)
- You used a locally built version of Python, and because it's locally built, it uses `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` instead of `/usr/lib/python2.7`, and because it doesn't have Debian/Ubuntu customizations, it doesn't check use `dist-packages`.

Solution: You should be able to add `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to your `/usr/local/bin/python`'s `sys.path`, but since you're using Ubuntu, it's easiest to let Ubuntu do the work for you:

- Use /usr/bin/python instead of a local version.
- Use Ubuntu's packages wherever possible (i.e., use `apt-get` instead of `pip`).
- Use virtualenv for the rest (to keep a clean separation between Ubuntu-packaged and personally installed modules).

I'd go so far as to uninstall the local version of Python and delete `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`, to ensure that no further mismatches occur.  If you don't want to be that drastic, then you can edit your $PATH to put `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin` to run the system version of Python by default.

Comment: _"Use virtualenv for the rest (to keep a clean separation between Ubuntu-packaged and personally installed modules)."_ Doesn't Ubuntu PIP install to `/usr/local/`?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - Yes, it does. I'm just really paranoid about separating personal modules from systemwide (`/usr` and `/usr/local`) modules, but thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

Try downloading the zip file from https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko and running this command in the unzipped directory :

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two others methodes for add modules in python :

**The first :**

1. Download the package.
2. Create directory and paste the package in it.
3. Tap in the terminal :
4. export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path_of_package

**The second :**

4. open python interpreter:
5. `import sys`
6. `sys.path.insert(0, "path_of_package")`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing only through commands.

1. Download paramiko package from git using this command: `git clone https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko.git`
2. Go to unzipped directory and run `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<path_to_paramiko>`
3. If you find libffi package not found then run this command: `sudo apt-get install libffi6 libffi-dev` and If you haven't properly installed the header files and static libraries for python dev then run this command: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, mind the version of python, if the error was reported by python3, then install python3's paramiko.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3, type the below command

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install paramiko --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score -1):

try type pi then tap, this give you this

:$ pi

pic              piconv           pidstat          pinentry-curses  ping6

```
       pip3             pivot_root
```

pic2graph        pidof            pinentry         ping             pinky

```
        pip3.6
```

then you type in whereis pip3

$ whereis pip3

pip3: /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 /usr/local/bin/pip3

xg@xx-ppmaster:/xg/scripts/pyth

$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install paramiko

This should let you install paramiko

more on python installation

https://danieleriksson.net/2017/02/08/how-to-install-latest-python-on-centos/