# Ubuntu 14.04: ImportError: No module named client

Tags: python, ubuntu, paramiko

I tried to use Paramiko in my Python 2.7, but I can't use it on my script.

I also install all packet

```
sudo pip install paramiko
pip install paramiko
sudo apt-get install python-paramiko
```

But It doesn't work

See my Script

```
 #!/usr/bin/python 
 #

 from paramiko.client import SSHClient
 import paramiko
 client = SSHClient

 client.load_system_host_keys()
 client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 client.connect("192.168.1.60")
 stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls -la")

 if stderr.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
    print stderr.channel.recv_exit_status()
    print stderr.read()

 else:
    print stdout.read()
```

It returns

```
   vitor@vitor-pc:~/Linux/Python/Arquivos de Configuração/Paramiko$ python paramiko.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "paramiko.py", line 4, in <module>
   from paramiko.client import SSHClient
   File "/home/vitor/Linux/Python/Arquivos de Configuração/Paramiko/paramiko.py", line 4, in <module>
   from paramiko.client import SSHClient
   ImportError: No module named client
```

I also tried to use this [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991319/ubuntu-python-no-module-named-paramiko) and and delete my /usr/local/lib/python2.7 But nothing change.

This error appear only in Ubuntu? Or my code is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
 vitor@vitor-pc:~/Linux/Python/Arquivos de Configuração/Paramiko$ python paramiko.py
```

You have named your own script as `paramiko.py` thus python thinks your own script is the where it can find the 'paramiko' module. But it isn't. Just rename your file to something else and you will be fine.

Comment: And one question, I remove my /usr/local/lib/python2.7, I will have any problem in future?

Comment: Glad to have helped! Don't touch /usr/local/lib/python2.7 that will be needed by countless packages that are installed on your system. In fact your system might even become unusable if you do so! If you have already deleted it please reinstall it asap

Comment: Humm, how can I reinstall?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python ought to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two others methodes for add modules in python :

**The first :**

1. Download the package.
2. Create directory and paste the package in it.
3. Tap in the terminal :
4. export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path_of_package

**The second :**

1. open python interpreter:
2. `import sys`
3. `sys.path.insert(0, "path_of_package")`